# Separar inteiro por caractere

Tags: c

Tenho um vetor de inteiros:
`int nums[10] = { 1234, 4761814, 9161451, 14357 };`

Quero saber como separo esses números, exemplo, o primeiro elemento virar um vetor assim:
`{1, 2, 3, 4}` ou seja, separar o inteiro, pois preciso por cada numero desse em uma posição de uma matriz.

Comment: Você quer um vetor de caracteres (ex.: `'1'`) ou de inteiros (ex.: `1`)? Respondi para inteiros, mas é fácil adaptar caso você queira `char`s.

Comment: Inteiro mesmo, é mais fácil de manipular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa, para cada inteiro, saber quantos dígitos decimais ele ocupa. Se você tiver à mão uma função de logaritmo, melhor, senão vá multiplicando uma variável por `10` até ela ficar maior que o número:

```
int numero = 1234;
int qtosDigitos = 1;
int limite = 10;
while ( numero >= limite ) {
    qtosDigitos++;
    limite *= 10;
}
```

Então é só criar o array com esse tamanho, e ir pegando os dígitos um a um:

```
int* digitos = (int*)malloc(qtosDigitos * sizeof(int));
for ( int i = 0 ; i < qtosDigitos ; i++ ) {
    limite /= 10;
    digitos[i] = (numero / limite) % 10;
}
```

Nota: essa solução só se aplica a números não-negativos.

Agora é só iterar sobre o array e fazer isso número por número:

```
int** digitosNums = (int**)malloc(tamanhoNums * sizeof(int*));
for ( int t = 0 ; t < tamanhoNums ; t++ ) {
    int numero = nums[t];
    ... // Código acima
    digitosNums[t] = digitos;
}
```

Nota: conforme já explicado em [sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91310/215), a linguagem C não oferece meios de descobrir dinamicamente o tamanho de um array, de modo que você precisa guardar essa informação em algum lugar ou usar um terminador nulo quando aplicável. O exemplo acima não faz isso, então cuidado ao adaptar.

Comment: Valeu matou duas dúvidas em uma só resposta!

Answer (score 2):

Fiz essa função para seu problema:

```
void desmembrar(int num, int *array){
     int i=0, div = 10, prediv = 1, numchar = 0;
     while(num - numchar){
          int aux =  num % div;
          int dif = numchar;
          numchar = aux;
          aux -= dif;
          aux /= prediv;
          prediv = div;
          div *= 10;
          array[i] = aux;
          i++;    
     }
     //inverte o array
     numchar = -1; i = 0;
     for(numchar; prediv != 1; numchar++) prediv /=10;
     for(i ; i != numchar && numchar > i; i++){
        int aux = array[numchar];
        array[numchar] = array[i];
        array[i] = aux; numchar --;
     }    
}
```

Basta passar por parâmetro o numero que você deseja separar, e um array de tamanho compatível onde será colocado o número separado.