# Pegar tamanho de um vetor de caracteres?

Tags: c

Exemplo de vetor:
`char nome[10] = {'b', 'r', 'a', 's', 'i','l'};`

Primeiramente, apesar de meu vetor ter 10 posição só estou usando seis, e quero saber como pego justamente esse comprimento, que no caso seria 6. Em resumo como pego o numero de caracteres presentes em uma string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A definição

```
char nome[10] = {'b', 'r', 'a', 's', 'i', 'l'};
```

é igual a

```
char nome[10] = {'b', 'r', 'a', 's', 'i', 'l', 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

por isso podes usar a função `strlen()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char nome[10] = {'b', 'r', 'a', 's', 'i', 'l'};
    printf("%d elementos.\n", (int)strlen(nome));
    return 0;
}
```