# Determinar se todos os dígitos são iguais

Tags: algoritmo, números, representação-numérica

Recebe como parâmetro um valor numérico. Por exemplo, 888 ou 546. E tenho uma função que retorna um valor um *booleano* `true` se todos os números forem iguais ou `false` se forem diferentes.

Como procedo com o algoritmo?

Comment: Duas opções: 1) transforme o número em string (representação decimal, é claro) e veja se todos os caracteres são iguais; 2) Faça uma série de divisões inteiras por 10 e resto da divisão por 10, e compare se os resultados são todos iguais.

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: ["Separar inteiro por caractere"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91308/215)

Comment: 'Se todos os números são iguais' você quer dizer que todos os digitos são iguais ou você vai receber 888, 546 e testar se 888 e 546 são iguais? Na verdade faz pouca diferença. Seria bom especificar qual o tipo de dado que será dado como entrada (string, int, float, etc).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Uma resposta em C#, utilizando o método de comparar os caracteres de uma `string`:

```cs
public bool TodosIguais( int num ) {
  char comparar = num.ToString()[0];
  foreach( var n in num.ToString() ) {
    if ( comparar != n ) { return false; }
  }
  return true;
}
```

**Editação**

A mesma resposta, de uma forma mais compacta, utilizando `extension methods` e `LINQ`:

```cs
//criar o classe
public static class Extencoes {
  public static bool TodosIguais( this int num ) {
    return num.ToString().All(c=>c.Equals(num.ToString().First()));
  }
}

//use-o
int numero = 5;
if ( numero.TodosIguais() ) { Console.WriteLine("Todos iguais."); }
```

Answer (score 32):

- Obtenha o número de casas decimais de um dado número original **O** usando a fórmula `Floor(Log10(numero)) + 1`

Exemplo:

```
O = 99999  
X = floor(log10(99999)) + 1 = 5
```

- Gere um número **N** que possua o dígito 1 repetido **X** vezes

Exemplo:

```
N = 11111
```

- Divida o número original O por N. Se a divisão for inteira, o número é uma repetição.

Exemplo:

```
O / N = 99999 / 11111 = 9.0 ; verdadeiro.
```

Answer (score 28):

- 1. Seja X o número original.
- 2. Divida X por 10 e obtenha o resto, chame-o de R1.
- 3. Repita enquanto X for maior que zero:

  - 3.1. Atribua a R2 o resto da divisão de X por 10.
  - 3.2. Se R1 for diferente de R2, retorne falso.
  - 3.3. Atribua a X o quociente da divisão inteira de X por 10.
- 4. Retorne verdadeiro.

Observe que esta abordagem funciona usando apenas a matemática, sem precisar converter o número para string ou para lista em momento algum.

Veja aqui o algoritmo acima implementado em JavaScript, incluindo o código de teste:

```js
function digitosIguais(x) {
  let r1 = x % 10;               // Passo 2.
  while (x > 0) {                // Passo 3.
    let r2 = x % 10;             // Passo 3.1.
    if (r2 !== r1) return false; // Passo 3.2.
    x = Math.floor(x / 10);      // Passo 3.3.
  }
  return true;                   // Passo 4.
}

function teste(numero) {
  document.writeln(numero + (digitosIguais(numero) ? "" : " não") + " tem todos os dígitos iguais.<br>");
}

teste(5555);
teste(88);
teste(9);
teste(11);
teste(0);
teste(123);
teste(765);
teste(9999998);
teste(800);
teste(404);
```

Clique no botão azul <kbd>► Executar</kbd> acima para testar e observe o resultado.

Answer (score 27):

Brincando às charadas de magia negra:

1) Um comando perl que lê da STDIN e escreve OK se for tudo números iguais

```
perl -E 'say "OK" if <> =~ /^(\d)\1*$/'
```

2) um algoritmo:

```
f(a) =  int((a*9+10)/10) % 10**(int(log10 a)) == 0
```

Comment: Excelente resposta, mas acho que o **`≠`** deveria ser um **`=`**.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, tens toda a razão:  deixei-me levar pela beleza do unicode :)

Answer (score 23):

Implementação em javascript da fórmula provida [na resposta do JJoao](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94050/132).

Também inclui os testes.

```js
function digitosIguais(a) {
  return a === 0 || Math.floor((a * 9 + 10) / 10) % Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(a))) === 0;
}

function teste(numero) {
  document.writeln(numero + (digitosIguais(numero) ? "" : " não") + " tem todos os dígitos iguais.<br>");
}

teste(5555);
teste(88);
teste(9);
teste(11);
teste(0);
teste(123);
teste(765);
teste(9999998);
teste(800);
teste(404);
```

Clique no botão azul <kbd>► Executar</kbd> acima para testar e observe o resultado.

Answer (score 22):

## Com expressões regulares

Usando expressões regulares é fácil implementar essa idéia em qualquer linguagem: `^(\d)\1*$`

#### Explicando

`^` marco o início da string

`(\d)` obtenho um dígito numérico

`\1` o caractere seguinte é igual ao dígito que obtive

`*` esse caractere pode se repetir várias vezes, ou nenhuma

`$` marco o final da string (como estou marcando o início e o final, garanto que não haverá nenhum caractere extra na string)

## Implementando em javascript

#### Fiz uma função para facilitar o uso

```js
function digitosIguais(numero) {
  return !!numero.toString().match(/^(\d)\1*$/);
}
```

#### Explicando

`!!` é para transformar o resultado em boleano

`toString()` é para converter o número em string, antes de aplicar a expressão regular

#### Testes

```js
console.log( digitosIguais(88888889) ); // => false
console.log( digitosIguais(88888888) ); // => true
```

Comment: Caramba, que regex dahora.

Answer (score 20):

## Java 8 com *chars stream*

Em Java 8 fica fácil com *streams*:

```java
boolean digitosIguais(Long numero) {
    return numero.toString().chars().distinct().count() == 1;
}
```

## Loop tradicional nod dígitos

Ou, se preferir, um algoritmo tradicional:

```java
boolean digitosIguais(Long numero) {
    char[] digitos = numero.toString().toCharArray();
    for (int i = 1; i < digitos.length; i++) {
        if (digitos[0] != digitos[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

## Sequências de dígitos pré-definidos

Outra ideia seria comparar o número com uma sequência pré-definida:

```java
String[] repeticoes = {
    "11111111111111111111", 
    "22222222222222222222", 
    ..., 
    "99999999999999999999"
};

boolean digitosIguais(Long numero) {
    if (numero <= 0l) return false;
    String s = numero.toString();
    String repeticao = repeticoes[Integer.parseInt(numero.charAt(0))];
    return s.equals(repeticoes.substring(0, numero.length()));
}
```

## Pré-calculo das possíveis combinações

Ou ainda calcular as combinações possíveis e depois identificar se o número está nesse conjunto, o que resulta num tempo praticamente constante de busca:

```java
Set<Long> repeticoes = new HashSet<>();
for (long i = 1L; i <= 9L; i++) {
    for (long j = i; j > 0 && j < 1000000000000000000L; j = j * 10L + i ) {
        repeticoes.add(j);
    }
}

boolean digitosIguais(Long numero) {
    return repeticoes.contains(numero);
}
```

O código acima resulta num conjunto com 162 números.

Answer (score 19):

- Algoritmos implementados usando **Javascript.**

---

**Algoritmo #1**

```js
    function digitosIguais(valor) {
      valor = valor.toString();
    
      for (i = 1; i < valor.length; i++)
        if (valor[0] != valor[i])
          return false;
    
      return true;
    }
```

**Explicação**:

1. Converte o valor para o tipo String (`valor.toString()`)
2. Loop começa na segunda posição (`i = 1`) sendo que a condição é o tamanho da string (`valor.length`)
3. Caso o primeiro valor for diferente do item da iteração (`valor[0] != valor[i]`), retorna false (não é igual) e sai da função
4. Se não: `return true` (igual)

**Exemplo funcional:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjcqyazk/)

---

**Algoritmo #2**

```js
    function digitosIguais2(sequencia){
        sequencia = sequencia.toString();
    
        for (i = 0; i < sequencia.length - 1; i++)
            if (sequencia.charAt(i) != sequencia.charAt(i + 1))
                return false;
    
        return true;
    }
```

1. Converte o valor para o tipo String (`sequencia.toString()`)
2. Loop com a condição tamanho da string menos 1 (`sequencia.length - 1`)
3. Caso a próxima posição for diferente da atual (`sequencia.charAt(i) != sequencia.charAt(i + 1)`) retorna false (não é igual).

- **Observação:** Utilizei o método `charAt` que retorna o valor de uma posição de um array.

4. Se não: `return true` (igual).

**Exemplo funcional:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2cpryprf/)

Answer (score 15):

Usando C#, pode também usar os operadores *bitwise*, fazendo uma comparação binária:

```cs
public bool TodosIguais( int original ) {
  var deveSer = int.Parse(new string(original.ToString()[0], original.ToString().Length));
  return ( deveSer | original ) == original;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Não sei se você queria só se os números fossem iguais, então me atrevi e fiz também uma palíndromo :D

Eita desculpa, a do Palíndromo é seguinte, o palíndromo é uma palavra (no contexto eu usei número) que lendo da esquerda pra direita, e da direita pra esquerda tem o mesmo significado (exemplo, "somos", "osso"). Então no `isPalindromo` eu peguei o parâmetro e passei para uma `String` e depois eu fiz um `for` do tamanho da `String` até zero, para pegar a palavra e passar para outra `String`, só que ela invertida. E no final eu vejo se ela é igual, a que veio pelo o parâmetro e a que eu inverti.

E o `isNumero` eu só peguei o primeiro número e vi nos números seguintes se existe algum que seja diferente. Porque se for diferente, já não é igual e posso dar um `break` pra sair do laço.

```java
public class Teste2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isPalindromo(3334333));
        System.out.println(isNumero(333333));
    }

    public static boolean isNumero(Integer valor) {
        boolean retorno = true;

        String numero = String.valueOf(valor);

         char elemento = numero.charAt(0);

        for(int i = 0;i < numero.length();i++){

            if(numero.charAt(i) != elemento){
                retorno = false;

            }
        }

        return retorno;
    }

    public static boolean isPalindromo(Integer valor) {
        boolean retorno = false;

        String numero = String.valueOf(valor);

        String numeroInvertido = "";

        for(int i = numero.length() - 1; i >= 0;i--){
            numeroInvertido += numero.charAt(i);
        }

        if(numero.equals(numeroInvertido)){
            retorno = true;
        }

        return retorno;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seria legal você explicar sua lógica pro OP.

Comment: Qual é o propósito do `isPalindromo`?

Comment: Eita desculpa, a do Palíndromo é  seguinte, o Palíndromo  é uma palavra (no contexto eu usei numero) que lendo da esquerda pra direita, e da direita pra esquerda tem o mesmo significado exemplo "somos","osso".
Então no isPalindromo eu peguei o parâmetro e passei para uma String e depois eu fiz um for do tamanho da String ate zero, para pegar a palavra e passar para outra String só que ela invertida.E no final eu vejo se ela é igual, a que veio pelo o parâmetro e a que eu inverti.

Comment: E os isNumero eu só pequei o primeiro numero e vi os números seguintes existe algum que seja diferente, pq se for diferente já não é igual e posso dar um break pra sair do laço.

Comment: Eu sei o que um palíndromo, eu só estou perguntando porque foi que você adicionou isso na sua resposta.

Comment: Não basta ser número e palíndromo para que todos os dígitos sejam iguais. Por exemplo, `1001` é palíndromo mas não atende ao que foi perguntado.

Comment: @kcpo Até acho legal sua iniciativa de compartilhar um código conosco, mas é bom ao menos explicar logo no começo do texto que é só um complemento, e que não é a resposta ao que foi perguntado. Isto pode evitar confusão para os futuros visitantes do site. O ideal é se ater ao que foi perguntado, mas se for para "desviar" da proposta inicial, o aviso pode tornar a resposta mais aceitável.

Answer (score 7):

**Contribuir com minha versão em Haskell:**

```
digitosSaoIguais :: Int -> Bool
digitosSaoIguais x = and $ map (== head xs) (tail xs)
    where xs = show x
```

- `show` converte o número `x` para String (lista de Char).
- agora `xs` é uma lista de Char, i.e. `546` vira `['5','4','6']`.
- `map (== head xs) (tail xs)` compara cada elemento de `tail xs` com o primeiro elemento da lista (`head xs`), e.g. `['5' == '4','5' == '6']`.
- `and` retorna `True` se todos os elementos de `tail xs` forem iguais ao primeiro elemento da lista.

Answer (score 3):

A primeira coisa que penseu foi fazer por potencia, contudo nenhuma resposta o fez :

```js
 

function checkEqual(num){
    var len = num.toString().length;            // VERIFICA QUANTOS CARACTERES ESTAO ENVOLVIDOS
    if(len == 1) return false;                  // SE COMPOSTO POR 1 NUMERO NAO GERA ERRO
    var n = parseInt(num.toString()[0]);        // PRIMEIRO NUMERO
    var r = Math.pow(n, len);                   // RESULTADO DA POTECIA DO PRIMEIRO NUMERO PELO TAMANHO
    var s = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){               // REALIZA A MULTIPLICACAO DE CADA ELEMENTO VINCULADO
        s *= parseInt(num.toString()[i]) || 0;  // SE ALGUM ELEMENTO NAO FOR NUMERICO MULTIPLICA POR 0
    }

    return r == s;                              // SE POTENCIA IGUAL AO RESULTADO DA MULTIPLICACAO
                                                // ENTAO SAO TODOS IGUAIS
}

function writeln(str){
    document.writeln(str+"<br/>");
}

writeln(checkEqual(555));
writeln(checkEqual(565));
writeln(checkEqual(5));
writeln(checkEqual(78));
writeln(checkEqual(11));
```

#### OBS

Eu adotaria a do REGEX `(\d)\1+`.

Comment: Sua solução nem sempre está correta: `checkEqual(214);` retorna `true`, porque `2³ = 8` e `2 * 1 * 4 = 8` também :)

Comment: @tayllan de fato. Não pensei em números baixos :/

Answer (score 3):

Considerando que o argumento recebido pela função vai ser do tipo numérico, você pode fazer um assim:

- cast do argumento para *string*;
- um laço de repetição (*loop*) de `0` a `9`;
- em cada repetição:

  - preencher uma *string* (*pad*) vazia: `''` até o `length` do argumento **com o número do controle da repetição**;
  - compara a string do *pad* com o cast do argumento e retorna `true` caso sejam iguais;
- senão, ao sair do laço de repetição a função retorna `false`;

---

Exemplo prático, em **JavaScript**:

<sup>(já com tratamento de erro)</sup>

```js
function digitosIguais(num) {
    if (typeof num != 'number')
        throw 'digitosIguais espera um argumento tipo número!';

    if (num.toString().length <= 1)
        return false;

    for (let iguais, i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        iguais = ('').padStart(num.toString().length, i);
        if (num == iguais)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(digitosIguais(122223456)); // false
console.log(digitosIguais(1111111111)); // true
console.log(digitosIguais(0)); // false
console.log(digitosIguais(1)); // false
console.log(digitosIguais(01)); // false
console.log(digitosIguais('12')); // erro
```

O interessante é que essa teoria, apesar de simples, é compatível com as principais linguagens.

E, dependendo do caso, pode aproveitar apenas o pedaço do laço de repetição nas suas funções, como por exemplo, de validação de CPF, CNPJ e afins.

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução é calcular se o número é um *repdigit*!

Segundo a [Fundação OEIS](http://oeis.org/wiki/Repdigit_numbers) um número *repdigit* é um numero natural positivo que composto por apenas repetições de um mesmo o dígito `d` tal que `0 < d < B` onde `B` é a base numérica em que o *repdigit* está representado.

```
d
dd
ddd
dddd
...
∞
```

[Na Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repdigit) é informado que *repdigit* são a representação na base numérica `B` do número [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] onde `x|0<x<B, x∈ℕ` é o dígito repetido e `y|1<y, y∈ℕ` é o número de repetições.
Ainda na Wikipédia foi dado o exemplo *do repdigit* `77777` na base `10` é [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

Voltando ao problema proposto, o algoritmo para conhecer se um número `n` inteiro é um *repdigit* na base numérica `b`, seria:

- Testar se o número é um inteiro. Caso não seja um inteiro não é *repdigit*.
- Obter o valor absoluto de `n` pois negativos não podem ser testados diretamente com a formula.
- Obter um digito `x` de `n` na base numérica `b`.
- Calcular `y` a quantidade de dígitos que compõe `n` na base numérica `b`.
- Retornar o resultado da comparação entre `n` e o *repdigit* `x * (b ** y - 1) / (b - 1);` se forem iguais `n` é um *repdigit*.

A implementação desse algoritmo pode ser apresentada como uma função em javascript ou outra linguagem:

```js
/**
 * A função isRepdigit() verifica se um numero é um inteiro repdigit.
 * O parâmetro n é o número a ser testado como repdigit.
 * O parâmetro b é a base numérica em que n será testado como repdigit.
 * Retorna true caso n é é um inteiro repdigit em caso contrário retorna false.
 */
function isRepdigit(n, b = 10) {
  if (!Number.isInteger(n)) return false;
  n = Math.abs(n);
  const x = n % b;
  const y = Math.floor(Math.log(n) / Math.log(b)) + 1;

  return n == x * (b ** y - 1) / (b - 1);
}

console.log(isRepdigit(777777777777777));
console.log(isRepdigit(777777777777778));
console.log(isRepdigit(127,2));            // 127₁₀ = 1111111₂
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma reposta em PHP, util para verificar se o cpf contem todos os números iguais

```
$digitos = 11111111111;
$todosIguais = true;
foreach(str_split($digitos) as $num){
    foreach(str_split($digitos) as $num2){
        if($num != $num2){
            $todosIguais = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$todosIguais) break;
}
if($todosIguais) return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia fazer da seguinte forma usando recursividade:

Exemplo em Java:

```
public static boolean allDigitsEqual(int x) {
    String xStr = Integer.toString(x);
    if (xStr.substring(0, 1).equals(xStr.substring(1, 2))) {
        return xStr.substring(1).length() == 1 ? true : allDigitsEqual(Integer.parseInt(xStr.substring(1)));            
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Exemplo em PHP:

```
function allDigitsEqual($x) {
    $xStr = (string) $x;
    if (substr($xStr, 0, 1) == substr($xStr, 1, 1)) {
        return strlen(substr($xStr, 1)) == 1 ? true : allDigitsEqual(substr($xStr, 1));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Exemplo em C#:

```
public static bool allDigitsEqual(int x)
{
    String xStr = x.ToString();
    if (xStr.Substring(0, 1) == xStr.Substring(1, 1))
    {
        return xStr.Substring(1).Length == 1 ? true : allDigitsEqual(Int32.Parse(xStr.Substring(1)));
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```