# Como inverter um inteiro?

Tags: c#, .net, algoritmo

Observe esse enunciado:

```
/*
 * Faça um programa que peça um numero inteiro positivo e em seguida mostre
 * este numero invertido. Exemplo:
 *  o 12376489 
 *      => 98467321
 *      
 */

Console.Write("Informe um número inteiro para ser invertido: ");
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string s = Convert.ToString(n);

for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
  string a = s.Substring(i - 1, 1);
  s += a;
}
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Não estou conseguindo, está lançando uma exceção `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239450/64969

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uma solução seria utilizando essa função que criei:

```
 public static void Inverter(int numero)
        {

            string valor = numero.ToString();
            string resultado = "";
            for(int i = valor.Length; i >0; i--)
            {
                resultado += valor[i-1];
            }


            Console.WriteLine(valor);
        }
```

Observação: Seu código está dando erro porque você inicializou seu **for** com o valor que você lê e não a quantidade de caracteres a ser percorrido.

Nesse caso o valor 123 por exemplo tentaria executar 123 vezes em seu for, enquanto temos apenas 3 caracteres, o que ocasionou em seu erro: **ArgumentOutOfRangeException**

1. Abaixo você recebe em n o valor digitado e Converte para inteiro, para converter abaixo novamente para string.
2. Você inicializar a variável de controle do seu **FOR** com o valor de entrada e não com a quantidade de caracteres que no caso é o que realmente nos interessa.

   **Nessa parte**: *Você inicializa n com o valor inserido, 
   logo abaixo no seu for, você percorre até o valor inserido ao invés da quantidade de caracteres que é o que nos interessa nesse caso.*

   int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

   ```
      string s = Convert.ToString(n);
      for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
   ```

Alteração necessária no seu código:

```
Console.Write("Informe um número inteiro para ser invertido: ");
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string s = Convert.ToString(n);
        string resultado = "";

        for (int i = n.ToString().Length; i > 0; i--)
        {
            string a = s.Substring(i - 1, 1);
            resultado += a;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(resultado);
```

Pontos que alterei:

1. Você estava percorrendo em seu FOR, o valor inserido, sendo que o que nos importa é a quantidade de caracteres.
2. Você estava utilizando a variável s para concatenar, porém nela já havia o valor que estava sendo lido pelo método substring.

Comment: Perfeito cara, muito obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado, só lembrando que como você está trabalhando com entrada de usuário, é interessante utilizar um try/cath. Para garantir que a entrada realmente é um número.

Comment: Não, se está trabalhando com entrada de usuário, é interessante validar o dado, exceção é para casos excepcionais, onde se espera o erro não se deve usar `try-catch`, por isso criaram soluções melhores que exceção.

Answer (score 15):

Normalmente esses exercícios são para demonstrar a capacidade de montar o melhor algoritmo, e não ir pelo caminho mais fácil, por isto eu faria matematicamente.

Aproveitei para consertar o problema que se a digitação não for válida quebrava a aplicação. Também fiz a validação que o enunciado pedia.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Write("Informe um número inteiro para ser invertido: ");
        if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var numero) && numero >= 0) return;
        var invertido = 0;
        while (numero > 0) {
           invertido = invertido * 10 + numero % 10;
           numero /= 10;
        }
        WriteLine(invertido);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3kqQxw). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l8Fwnv). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/InvertNumber.cs).

Se quiser mesmo fazer com *string* faça da maneira correta, mesmo que para um exercício não seja necessário:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Text;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Write("Informe um número inteiro para ser invertido: ");
        var texto = ReadLine();
        if (!int.TryParse(texto, out var numero) && numero >= 0) return;
        var invertido = new StringBuilder(texto.Length);
        for(int i = texto.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) invertido.Append(texto[i]);
        WriteLine(invertido);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/aWkdST). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZVPFgt). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/InvertNumber.cs).

Answer (score 8):

#### Analisando  o código

Existem alguns erros na sua implementação. Fiz as correções e vou comentar abaixo.

```
Console.Write("Informe um número inteiro para ser invertido: ");
string numeroDigitado = Console.ReadLine();
int numeroConvertido = Int32.Parse(numeroDigitado);
string invertido = "";

for (int i = numeroDigitado.Length; i > 0; i--) {
    string letra = numeroDigitado.Substring(i - 1, 1);
    invertido += letra;
}

Console.WriteLine(invertido);
```

Primeiramente eu alterei o nome das suas variáveis para deixar um pouco mais fácil de ler. Isso não é uma regra.

Antes você estava recebendo uma string do Console, convertendo pra inteiro e depois convertendo para string novamente, uma dessas conversões é desnecessária. Pode ver minhas alterações nas linhas 2 e 3.

O seu `for` estava iniciando em `n`, que era sua entrada convertida em inteiro. O correto seria variar pela quantidade de caracteres do número. `1235` deve iterar 4 vezes e não 1235 vezes.

#### Outra solução

Uma manipulação fácil seria pegar esse inteiro e convertê-lo para um vetor de caracteres, utilizando o método `.ToCharArray()`, inverter essa array e voltar para inteiro.

```
public int ReverseInt(int input) {
    char[] vetor = input.ToString().ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(vetor);
    return Int32.Parse(new String(vetor));
}
```