# Como gerar caracteres ou string aleatórios?

Tags: c#, string, random

Como especificar a quantidade de vezes que um caracteres pode repetir?

Ex: tenho **ABC**, onde **C** deve repetir 4 vezes em uma nova `string` de 6 caracteres:

( **AB CC CC** ) ou (**AC CB CC**) ou ( **AC CC CB** )

> **A** só pode entrar na posição 1, 3, 5. 
>   **B** só pode entrar na posição 2, 4, 6. 
>   **C** pode entrar em qualquer posição.

- Não é permitido que apareça **AA** ou **BB**, apenas **AB**.

Exemplo não permitido:

> ( **AA CC CC** ) ou ( **CC AA CC** ) ou ( **CC CC AA** ) ou 
> ( **BB CC CC** ) ou ( **CC BB CC** ) ou ( **CC CC BB** ).

Espero todas essas combinações:

> **AC AC CC
>
>   AC CC CB
>
>   AC CB CC
>
>   AC CC AC
>
>   AB CC CC
>
>   CB AC CC
>
>   CB CC AC
>
>   CB CC CB
>
>   CB CB CC
>
>   CC AC AC
>
>   CC AC CB
>
>   CC CB AC
>
>   CC CB CB
>
>   CC CC AB
>
>   CC AB CC**

(Não precisa está nessa ordem, porém deve ter todas essas saídas)

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6425/69359

Comment: @RovannLinhalis fiz muitas edições na outra pergunta, ai pensei em refazer.

Comment: sim, mas o correto é utilizar das edições mesmo, como pode ver na reposta do Renan que compartilhei, o sistema automaticamente pode bloquear sua conta.

Comment: Poderia detalhar um pouco melhor o seu problema e comentar o código para que vejamos sua linha de pensamento?

Comment: Gostaria de fazer uma permutação de 6 caracteres com ABC;

Comment: Criei duas string disse a quantidade de vezes coloquei em uma nova string e mandei imprimi o randômico, só que era para juntar juntas as duas string depois fazia o randômico e imprimia.. ainda vou ver como fazer as restrições.

Comment: Talves essa questão do [StackOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132758/words-combinations-without-repetition) te ajude.

Comment: Consigo resolver essa questão através de uma gramática regular/máquina de estados finitos. Existem outras alternativas, pensei em cadeia de Markov, mas a limitação de pelo menos 4 **C**s fica difícil modelar em cadeias de Markov tradicionais

Answer (score 6):

Vou atacar o caso específico de sua pergunta. Dentre tantas possíveis maneiras de se gerar cadeias de informação aleatórias, achei estas as mais significativas. Mas antes, um pouco de conceito.

## É tudo informação

Antes de mais nada, gostaria de salientar que letras, números, e o que mais está sendo tratado aqui não passa de informação que está sendo gerada para ser consumida por outro processo.

No caso de cadeias (ou palavras), as informações que as compõe são:

1. seus caracteres
2. a posição de cada um de seus caracteres

Então, para cada letra, são necessárias duas informações. Podemos então representar cadeias de letras como um [conjunto de tuplas de caracter/posição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240048/64969). Por exemplo, a palavra `banana`:

```
{
  ('b',0),
  ('a',1),
  ('n',2),
  ('a',3),
  ('n',4),
  ('a',5)
}
```

Como temos a garantia que o segundo termo da tupla sempre vai ser único (caso não fosse, então assumiríamos que uma palavra poderia ter duas ou mais letras na mesma posição, o que não é o caso), então cada tupla formada é única e a cardinalidade do conjunto que gera determinada palavra é igual ao comprimento da palavra.

### Cada letra uma informação diferente? Talvez não

Vimos que uma palavra nada mais é do que um conjunto de tuplas de letra/posição. Para o seu caso específico, temos 3 letras possíveis para 6 posições. As letras são:

- `A`
- `B`
- `C`

Mas elas obedecem a certas restrições. Por exemplo, nas posições 0, 2 e 4 podemos ter `A` ou `C`, jamais `B`. Já para as posições 1, 3 e 5 podemos ter `B` ou `C`. Isso implica em dizer que, para uma posição `i` informada, a letra pode ser `C` ou `não-C`. Sem mais.

Por que disso? Porque a quantidade possível máxima de valores distintos em cada posição é 2: pode ser `{A,C}`, ou pode ser `{B,C}`. Portanto, podemos representar com apenas 1 bit de informação além da informação posicional qual é o caracter na posição específica. Como `C` é comum para os dois grupos de opções, ou se é `C` ou se é distinto de `C` (portanto `não-C`).

Portanto, para o seu caso em questão, basta que geremos uma sequência de 0s e 1s (com 0 representando `não-C` e 1, `C`), aplicado a restrição de possuir exatamente 4 vezes o bit 1 (o `C` precisa aparecer exatamente 4 vezes).

### Mas ainda podemos comprimir mais!

> Veja [What is NOT Random?](https://youtu.be/sMb00lz-IfE) (vídeo em inglês) para maiores detalhes.

Na sua listagem de saídas esperadas, a primeira palavra é `ACACCC`. Na representação de conjunto de tuplas letra/posição:

```
{
  ('A', 0),
  ('C', 1),
  ('A', 2),
  ('C', 3),
  ('C', 4),
  ('C', 5)
}
```

Como já foi discutido, a letra ser `A` ou `B` não carreia informação, portanto ou ela é `C` ou `não-C`, 1 ou 0:

```
{
  ('0', 0),
  ('1', 1),
  ('0', 2),
  ('1', 3),
  ('1', 4),
  ('1', 5)
}
```

Notou como os 1s estão em maioria? Pois bem, o diferencial entre essa palavra e esta outra palavra também válida é apenas uma troca de posições entre letras:

```
{
  ('1', 0),
  ('0', 1),
  ('0', 2),
  ('1', 3),
  ('1', 4),
  ('1', 5)
}
```

O que isso quer dizer então? Que eu só precisaria de uma única informação para diferenciar entre `ACACCC` e `CBACCC`. Porém o nosso modelo representacional não é mínimo o suficiente. A única informação real trocada foi a posição da posição da tupla letra/posição `('0', 0)` para `('0', 1)`. Como isso pode ser? Porque todas as posições que não tem 0 necessariamente tem 1, então preciso informar apenas as posições que contém 0. Como eu já sei qual o caracter a ser informado, ele deixou de ser informação, sendo desprezível. Portanto, as palavras `ACACCC` e `CBACCC` são representadas por, respectivamente:

```
{ 0, 2 }
{ 1, 2 }
```

### TL;DR

A representação da cadeia de caracteres é resumida apenas na descrição da posição das duas letras diferentes de `C` que estão na palavra. Todas as outra 4 posições são então `C`. Caso o índice seja par, a letra `não-C` é `A`, caso contrário é `B`. Note que as duas posições precisam ser distintas, caso contrário estaremos oferecendo uma palavra com cinco `C`s, o que não é o que desejamos.

## Gerando *uma* palavra aleatória com dados

Sabendo como representar a informação, gerar a resposta agora consiste em gerar dois números inteiros distintos entre 0 e 5 inclusive. Uma alternativa seria jogar dados:

[image: dois dados de 6 faces com resultados distintos, neste caso o resultado da rolagem foi 2 e 4]

Neste caso, a cadeia obtida seria `101011`, que equivale a `CBCBCC`. Caso o resultado fossem dois números iguais, bastaria jogar os dados novamente: dos 21 resultados possíveis, 15 são de números distintos, e cada um desses 15 tem o dobro de chances de acontecer perante um resultado de dois números iguais.

Porém não seria muito prático para o seu programa jogar dados para gerar a string... ou seria?

Para criar um "dado", precisamos de um gerador de números aleatórios. Neste caso, o gerador é um objeto da classe `Random`. Então é só gerar o número aleatório inteiro no intervalo `[0, 5]`, que se faz usando `Next(6)` (`Next(m)` gera um número inteiro no intervalo `[0, m)` aberto em `m`; como `[0, 5]` é equivalente nos inteiros a `[0, 6)`, o número passado foi 6). Para respeitar a aleatoriedade prevista pelo gerador de números aleatórios, sempre o mesmo gerador precisa ser chamado repetidas vezes para obter números "razoavelmente" aleatórios.

Então, o seu algoritmo consiste em achar dois números inteiros aleatórios distintos no intervalo `[0, 6)`. Então podemos sumarizá-lo assim:

```
// cria o gerador de números aleatórios
// você também pode prover esse gerador, no lugar de ficar criando um novo a cada instante
// reutilizar o mesmo gerador de números aleatórios nos garante a entropia máxima possível entre duas gerações de números 
Random r = new Random();

int a, b;

// gira os dados...
a = r.Next(6);
b = r.Next(6);

// insiste na rolagem de um dado até obter um resultado distinto
while (a == b) {
  b = r.Next(6);
}
```

Pronto, agora temos dois números inteiros aleatórios entre `[0, 6)`. Essa é toda a informação necessária para obter a cadeia de caracteres.

```
string cadeia = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  if (i == a || i== b) {
    // caso seja um dos números aleatórios, então é não-C
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      // posições pares não-C são dedicadas a A
      cadeia += "A";
    } else {
      // caso ímpar, B
      cadeia += "B";
    }
  } else {
    // caso contrário, preencha com C
    cadeia += "C";
  }
}
```

Então, após executar esse procedimento, temos uma string no formato desejado.

### Frequência das palavras

Para saber com que frequência cada palavra vai aparecer, temos a hipótese de rodar milhares de vezes e tirar a média ou tentar uma abordagem mais teórica. A teórica aparenta ser mais divertida.

A estratégia usada para geração de números aleatórios pela classe `Random` é um [gerador subtrativo](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Subtractive_generator) ([fonte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx)). Segundo a [fonte do Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Subtractive_generator), os desenvolvedores do *Freeciv* implicam que o cálculo usando essa estratégia subtrativa e um módulo gera [baixa entropia nos bits menos significativos](https://github.com/freeciv/freeciv/blob/master/utility/rand.c#L61).

Então, a entropia esperada para nosso caso não é das maiores. Então seria necessário rodar diversas vezes até obter as 15 palavras diferentes. Como a entropia é possivelmente baixa, pode-se esperar rodar em algumas palavras até obter uma outra nova.

## Caminhada errante

Uma outra alternativa é usar um "caminhada errante" para montar a palavra desejada. O que é isso?

Bem, o termo mais correto seria [*passeio aleatório*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passeio_aleat%C3%B3rio), mas caminhada errante soa mais natural. Imagine que você tem a seguinte grid:

[image: Grid 4x2 com C no eixo horizontal e não-C no eixo vertical, com os pares de inteiros devidamente marcados e com o ponto mais extremo circulado]

A melhor explicação que eu acho que há para caminhadas errantes é um vídeo do Infinite Series: [What is a Random Walk?](https://youtu.be/stgYW6M5o4k).

No caso em particular, vou pegar uma grid 4x2 (4 na horizontal e 2 na vertical) para a nossa caminhada errante. Então, só me falta definir as probabilidades de se dar os passos. Ah, também falta dizer o que são esses passos. Volto para o significado dos passos mais adiante, vou terminar o resto da modelagem da caminhada antes de entrar nos significados, mas já vou logo adiantando que dedico toda uma seção a explicar isso.

Como minha grid é finita, se o caminhante estiver na borda, ele não pode seguir mais naquela direção. Por exemplo, começando da origem, se nos dois primeiros passos o caminhante escolheu subir e subir, o terceiro passo necessariamente vai ser para a direita ou para baixo, pois ele não pode subir nem se mover para a esquerda, pois cairia do grid.

Também não me interessa *back-tracking*, então o caminhante sempre irá em direção ao destino final, que é a posição `(4,2)`. Ele não pode, portanto, se mover nem para baixo, nem para a esquerda, pois ambos seriam um *back-track* do caminho, ficando mais próximo da origem do que do destino após o passo.

> Note que, no meu andar, não estou usando o "andar do bêbado" como foi o exemplo que a Kelsey usou no vídeo. Minhas opções de movimento são mais limitadas para poder representar melhor o problema que estou atacando.

Então, já sei que movimentos para a esquerda ou para baixo sempre tem possibilidade de 0. Também sei que, após quaisquer dois passos para cima, o terceiro passo nesse mesmo sentido também tem chance 0, e análogo para 4 passos para a direita, com o quinto passo com chance 0.
Mas e os demais passos?

Eu gostaria que cada transição vertical do mesmo nível (como `(x, 0)` para `(x, 1)`) tenha a mesma chance *global* de ocorrer. Não me interessa diretamente a chance de se estar em cada estado, portanto posso manipular esses valores a vontade.

Para sair do primeiro nível e entrar no segundo, tenho 5 possibilidades:

- `(0, 0)` ==> `(0, 1)`
- `(1, 0)` ==> `(1, 1)`
- `(2, 0)` ==> `(2, 1)`
- `(3, 0)` ==> `(3, 1)`
- `(4, 0)` ==> `(4, 1)`

Então, ao todo, cada transação precisa ser disparada 20% das vezes.

Partindo da origem, antes do primeiro passo, tenho 100% de chance de que o caminhante está nessa posição em específico. Então, preciso de 20% de chance para a transação vertical.

Para o ponto `(1, 0)`, tenho agora 80% (4/5) de chance do caminhante estar nesse ponto. Então, necessito que, desses 80%, 25% (1/4) disparem a transação vertical (ficando um total global de 80% x 25% = 20%). Então, estando no ponto `(1, 0)`, temos:

- 1/4 de possibilidade de subir
- 3/4 de possibilidade de ir para a direita

De modo semelhante, apenas 3/5 de chance do caminhante chegará no ponto `(2, 0)`, portanto a transação vertical deve ser disparada 1/3 das vezes. Na posição `(3, 0)`, será 2/5 de chance de estar lá, portanto metade dos disparos deve ser feito para cima. Então, no final, temos 1/5 de chance do caminhante estar em `(4, 0)`, então precisamos de 100% dos disparos para cima. Como de qualquer sorte esse ponto está na ponta da grid, ele está coagido a ir para cima mesmo.

A forma geral nesse caso é:

- chance de disparo vertical na posição `(i, 0)`: `1/(5 - i)`
- chance de disparo horizontal na posição `(i, 0)`: `1 - 1/(5 - i) = (4 - i)/(5 - i)`

Para o caso do segundo disparo... bem, não tenho notícias animadoras em relação ao balanceamento. Vamos pegar a posição `(4, 1)`. Ela sempre disparará para cima, então a chance global dessa transação ser disparada é igual à chance global do caminhante estar na posição `(4, 1)` após 5 passos. Computando apenas a chance de sair do estado `(4, 0)`, temos 20% de chance. Então temos os 20% + um valor `S*X` do caminhante estar na posição `(3, 1)` (probabilidade de `S`) e se mover na horizontal (probabilidade de disparo `X`). Como o valor resultante esperado da saída é 20%, e também sabemos que `20% = 20% + S*X`, então temos que `S*X = 0`. Como existe uma chance não nula de o caminhante passar por essa posição, então `X` deve ser nulo.

Ou seja, se eu desejar que a probabilidade de disparo global das transações verticais chegar no terceiro nível, é necessário anular a possibilidade de disparos horizontais no segundo nível. Esse resultado pode ser alcançado a partir de uma extrapolação do que foi obtido com `X` no parágrafo anterior. Mas isso não é nem um pouco desejado. Talvez devamos inverter as probabilidades de disparo horizontal e vertical dos disparos do nível anterior?

Então, seguindo essa metodologia, essa é a minha tabela de disparos:

```
Ponto  V   H
-------------
(0,0) 1/5 4/5
(1,0) 1/4 3/4
(2,0) 1/3 2/3
(3,0) 1/2 1/2
(4,0)  1   0
(0,1) 4/5 1/5
(1,1) 3/4 1/4
(2,1) 2/3 1/3
(3,1) 1/2 1/2
(4,1)  1   0
(0,2)  0   1
(1,2)  0   1
(2,2)  0   1
(3,2)  0   1
(4,2) DESTINO
```

Nessa tabela, a coluna `Ponto` indica a probabilidade de disparo partindo desse ponto, a coluna `V` a probabilidade do disparo vertical e `H` de disparo vertical.

### Caminhando errantemente

Para esse caminhar, basta jogar uma probabilidade e contrapor com a tabela acima. Para gerar um número digno dessa probabilidade, basta chamar o método [`NextDouble()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) de um objeto da classe `Random`, se ele for menor do que o valor da tabela para a transação vertical, então dispara na vertical. Caso contrário, dispara na horizontal.

Por exemplo:

- se for obtido o valor 0.2, saindo da origem, então a transação seguida será para a direita
- se for obtido 0.49 da posição `(3,0)`, então seguirá para cima

Com isso, em um laço de 6 passos, obtemos um caminho que sai da origem e chega no destino `(4,2)`.

Exemplo de caminho:

[image: um exemplo de sequência de disparos, direita-cima-direita-direita-cima-direita]

### Semântica do caminho errante

Prometi que iria explicar isso depois de terminar a modelagem, não prometi?

Vamos voltar à primeira imagem:

[image: a primeira imagem de grid novamente]

Notou os eixos dela? O eixo horizontal é `C`, já o vertical é `C` com a barra de negação em cima, portanto `não-C`. Isso significa que um passo tomado para a vertical consiste na criação/consumo de uma letra do tipo `não-C`, já na horizontal seria o consumo de um `C` propriamente dito. Voltando para a representação binária, um passo vertical equivale a 0, já um horizontal equivale a 1.

Então, qual seria a sequência gerada pelo exemplo acima?

[image: recapitulando o desenho]

Seria `101101`, ou `CBCCAC` transformando a informação binária na cadeia final.

E se fosse desejado obter a palavra cujo binário é `101011`?

[image: caminho equivalente a <code>CBCBCC</code>]

Isso daria a palavra `CBCBCC`.

Com esses caminhos eu também posso representar dois `não-C`s consecutivos, como em `ABCCCC`. O binário equivalente é `001111`, então o desenho do caminho ficaria assim:

[image: caminho equivalente a <code>ABCCCC</code>]

### Curiosidades dessa modelagem

Como explicado no [vídeo sobre caminhadas errantes](https://youtu.be/stgYW6M5o4k), esse processamento é nada mais nada menos do que uma cadeia de Markov. E Chomsky em um de seus artigos seminais sobre linguagens formais [Three models for the description of language](https://chomsky.info/wp-content/uploads/195609-.pdf) descreveu como um simples processo de Markov finito consegue gerar uma linguagem de infinitas palavras (seção 2). Por sinal, logo nos primeiros parágrafos dessa seção, Chomsky descreve como criar processos de Markov para a *geração* de palavras.

Em outro artigo ([On Certain Formal Properties of Grammars](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/henglein/papers/chomsky1959.pdf)), Chomsky demonstra no Teorema 6 a Definição 9, a definição implica que processos de Markov finitos geram uma linguagem regular ao emitir caracteres ao disparar uma transação.

> Nota sobre a leitura de On Certain Formal Properties of Grammars][14](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/henglein/papers/chomsky1959.pdf): o que Chomsky definiu nesse artigo como *gramática regular* hoje conhecemos como [**forma normal de Chomsky para gramáticas  livres de contexto**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form)

Ora, nós não estamos disparando caracteres ao fazer transações? Sendo esse caracter 0 ou 1? Então nós temos aqui um processo de Markov, com quantidade finita de estados, que dispara caracteres. Portanto, sem nem mesmo perceber, acabamos por criar o [autômato finito determinístico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) que reconhece as palavras da sua linguagem. Note que, a nível de reconhecimento de palavras, a probabilidade de disparo do processo de Markov pode ser sumariamente ignorado. O fato de ser representado por uma linguagem regular significa que para reconhecer as palavras desejadas tem, também, uma expressão regular subjacente.

### Parece complicação demasiada essa história da caminhada errante, não?

Aparências podem enganar. No caso, o espaço disponível para ser errante tem mais possibilidade para variações no que você está querendo reconhecer/gerar do que a solução anterior.

Por exemplo, se precisar reconhecer com pelo menos um `não-C` e  no máximo dois `não-C`, com 6 letras ao todo? Então teríamos adicionado à grid os seguintes pontos:

- `(5,0)`
- `(5,1)`

Mas não faz sentido adicionar `(5,2)`, pois seriam necessários 7 letras (limite é de 6 letras).

Se for o caso de se fazer repetição dessa estrutura? Por exemplo, após achar uma sequência desse jeito, pode ter uma, duas ou infinitas sequências que seguem a mesma lógica de formação. Então estamos lidando com [Estrela de Kleene](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210716/64969) sobre essa linguagem de As, Bs e Cs, limitadas a 6 caracteres ao todo etc.

Sem falar que, graficamente fica mais bonito.

Então, por que não apresentar apenas essa opção de resposta? Porque essa, apesar de mais completa e generalizada, não é a mais simples. Por isso resolvi deixar ambas as opções. E também começar falando da mais simples para introduzir os conceitos a ser usado nessa parte mais completa soa mais natural ao leitor.

## Enumerando as strings

Apresentei duas abstrações de geração. Você pode usar ambas para gerar a enumeração de todas as palavras possíveis. Mas eu acho particularmente mais fácil a alternativa dos dois dados.

Como são só dois dados de 6 lados distintos, eu poderia simplesmente iterar por todas as 36 possibilidades e, em cada uma delas, verificar se é um lançamento válido ou não. Ou então eu posso ser mais esperto e só gerar possibilidades válidas.

Para ser válido, o segundo número precisa acontecer após o primeiro e, necessariamente, ser maior. Por que essa diferença agora, já que no algoritmo apresentado acima tanto fazia? Porque `(3,1)` é equivalente a `(1,3)` e assumindo essa limitação fica mais fácil programar.

Recapitulando, eu posso encapsular a rotina de geração descrita na seção anterior em uma função:

```
public static string geraPalavra(int a, int b) {
    string cadeia = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      if (i == a || i== b) {
        // caso seja um dos números aleatórios, então é não-C
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
          // posições pares não-C são dedicadas a A
          cadeia += "A";
        } else {
          // caso ímpar, B
          cadeia += "B";
        }
      } else {
        // caso contrário, preencha com C
        cadeia += "C";
      }
    }
    return cadeia;
}
```

E então bastaria chamar essa função com os argumentos devidamente preenchidos para enumerar **todas** as strings possíveis;

```
for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
    for (int b = a + 1; b < 6; b++) {
        string novaPalavra = geraPalavra(a, b);
        // faz algo com essa string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que a manha para essa questões é criar um vetor com as letrar e ficar sorteando elas dentro do vetor e conferindo o caractere anterior e se o C já apareceu quatro vezes, veja se o código abaixo te atende:

```
//vetor de char com as letras
            var letras = new char[3];
            letras[0] = 'A';
            letras[1] = 'B';
            letras[2] = 'C';
            var resposta = "";
            int numC = 0;
        while (resposta.Length < 6)
        {
            //gerando um aleatório dentro do intervalo do vetor
            var random = new Random();
            var i = random.Next(letras.Length);

            //caso a resposta tenha tamanho 0 qualquer letrar serve
            if (resposta.Length == 0)
            {
                resposta += letras[i];
                continue;
            }

            if (letras[i] == 'C')
                numC++;

            //o C sempre pode ser usado sempre até quatro vezes, mas o A só pode quando o anterior for B e vice versa
            if ((letras[i] == 'C' && numC < 4) || resposta[resposta.Length - 1] != letras[i])
                resposta += letras[i];
        }

        Console.Write(resposta);
```

Comment: O 'C' é obrigatório repetir 4 vezes. A e B são para complementar os 6 caracteres.

Answer (score 0):

Tente essa solução:

```
private static string Seleciona() {
    var origem = new List<char>() { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C' };
    var resultado = new StringBuilder();
    int indice;
    var rnd = new Random(GerarSeed());
    for (int i = (origem.Count - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        indice = rnd.Next(0, i);
        resultado.Append(origem[indice]);
        origem.RemoveAt(indice);
    }
    return resultado.ToString();

    int GerarSeed() {
        using (var rgn = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider()) {
            var rno = new byte[20];
            rgn.GetBytes(rno);
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(rno, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Um vetor contendo todos os caracteres já está pré-definido. O trabalho é selecionar aleatoriamente os elementos e, a cada seleção, o elemento é removido do vetor.

Para testar o código:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine(Seleciona());
    }
}
```

Comment: Tem outras forma de dizer quantas vezes o 'C' deve repetir?

Comment: O código resolveu a sua demanda?

Comment: Editei o pergunta do que eu espero.

Answer (score 0):

Isso deve resolver

```
public static Random random = new Random();

public static string Sortear()
{
    // posição 0, 2, 4
    int a = random.Next(6);

    //posição 1, 3, 5
    int b;
    do 
    {
        b = random.Next(6);
    } while(b == a);

    //string res = "a: "+a+" b: "+b +" -> ";
    string res = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (i == a && (a % 2 == 0))
        {
            res += "A";
        }
        else if (i == a && (a % 2 == 1))
        {
            res += "B";
        }
        else if (i == b && (b % 2 == 0))
        {
            res += "A";
        }
        else if (i == b && (b % 2 == 1))
        {
            res += "B";
        }
        else 
        {
            res += "C";
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Se quiser que exiba todos só precisa mudar o random por um for

```
public static string MostrarTodas()
{
    string res = "";
    for (int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
    {
        for (int b = a + 1; b < 6; b++)
        {
            res += "\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                if (i == a && (a % 2 == 0))
                {
                    res += "A";
                }
                else if (i == a && (a % 2 == 1))
                {
                    res += "B";
                }
                else if (i == b && (b % 2 == 0))
                {
                    res += "A";
                }
                else if (i == b && (b % 2 == 1))
                {
                    res += "B";
                }
                else 
                {
                    res += "C";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Não gerou todos. E também não sei como fazer para validar que cada grupo de 6 caracteres ou grupos de 3 pares sejam diferentes entre si. Ex: AC CC CB não tenha outro resultado AC CC CB.

Comment: Tinha entendido errado a pergunta, agora esta correto