# Como encontrar o nome da chave em um dicionário pelo valor contido dela?

Tags: python

Aqui vai um exemplo.

```
dicio = {'pizza': {'massa', 'ketchup'}, 'feijoada': {'feijão', 'linguiça'}}

user_input = 'feijão', 'linguiça' #Input
```

Como verificar se esse input está nos valores dessa lista e se estiver como posso a partir disso pegar o nome da chave que tem esse valores e printar pro usuário ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normalmente, isso que você está fazendo é o contrário de um mapeamento tradicional.

Agora, você pode transformar o seu multimapa em outro multimapa, dessa vez com chaves/valores invertidos. [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240048/64969) eu descrevo um pouco melhor um multimapa, então não vou voltar muito aos formalismos dessa definição.

```
reverse_multimapa = {}
for chave_original, valores in dicio.items():
    for valor in valores:
        try:
            # se chave existir, tudo funciona corretamente
            reverse_multimapa[valor].append(chave_original)
        except KeyError:
            # se chave não existir, vai cair aqui
            reverse_multimapa[valor] = [chave_original]
```

Então, a busca reversa seria apenas passar o valor desejado para o `reverse_multimapa` e obter seus valores. Note que, nesse caso, estou prevendo que o caso em que `'pizza'` e `'sanduíche'` tenham como um dos valores associados `'ketchup'`.

Neste caso:

```
print(reverse_multimapa['ketchup'])
```

Retornaria:

```
['pizza', 'sanduíche']
```

---

Uma alternativa usando dicionários puros do Python é usar o método `setdefault` no resgate. Isso evita o tratamento da exceção (ou o tratamento do `None`, caso seja usado o método `get`). Dica cortesia do [@jsbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/500/jsbueno) em [seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254607/como-encontrar-o-nome-da-chave-em-um-dicion%C3%A1rio-pelo-valor-contido-dela/254612#comment522354_254612).

```
reverse_multimapa = {}
for chave_original, valores in dicio.items():
    for valor in valores:
        reverse_multimapa.setdefault(valor, []).append(chave_original)
```

---

Como indicado pelo [@AndersonCarlosWoss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss) em [seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254607/como-encontrar-o-nome-da-chave-em-um-dicion%C3%A1rio-pelo-valor-contido-dela/254612#comment522341_254612), o que eu fiz ali com o `try-except` [já foi realizado no Python](https://xkcd.com/353/) de maneira muito eficiente e idiomática. Poderia ter usado o [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Por coincidência, o exemplo fornecido pela própria documentação é para criar multimapas.

Aproveitando, deixo aqui um aviso sobre o uso dessa estratégia aqui perante a estratégia anterior, documentada dentro do exemplo de uso do `collections.defaultdict`, que trata especificamente de criar lista caso o elemento não exista no dicionário e, caso exista, adicionar a ela:

> This technique is simpler and faster than an equivalent technique using dict.setdefault()

Em tradução livre:

> Essa técnica é mais simples e mais veloz do que a técnica equivalente usando dict.setdefault()

Usando o `collections.defaultdict`, ficaria assim a construção de `reverse_multimapa`:

```
reverse_multimapa = collections.defaultdict(list)
for chave_original, valores in dicio.items():
    for valor in valores:
        reverse_multimapa[valor].append(chave_original)
```

O uso de `reverse_multimapa` continua sendo idêntico, apenas sua criação está mais facilitada e legível.

Comment: Uma alternativa ao bloco `try/except` é utilizar o [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss muito mais simples, desconhecia isso.

Comment: Hoje em dia é dificil eu usar o `defaultdict dicionários padrão tem o método `setdefault` que daz a mesma coisa: `reverse_multimapa.setdefault(valor, []).append(chave_original)`

Comment: @jsbueno isso que dá conhecer o mínimo da linguagem o possível para escrever algoritmos. Obrigado pela dica, parece até mesmo mais elegante do que o `defaultdict`. A minha sensação é que em Python realmente é tudo com `import antigravity`, basta apenas se lembrar o que se deseja

Comment: o que eu ahco legal em Python é justamente isso - com o mínimo da linguagem fdá pra escrever qualquer algoritmo. As facilidades e boas práticas, se adiquire com  o tempo e fazendo - e interagir por aqui é estar "fazendo".

Comment: Ja que vocês estão aí, deem uma olhada no "extradict' - é um módulo meio de brinquedo, meio sério, onde coloco uns dicionários experimentais. Um deles é um dicionário que torna o retorno "valor, chave" automático (`extradict.BijectiveDict`)

Comment: É fácil de achar no Google, mas de qualquer sorte vou deixar aqui o link: https://github.com/jsbueno/extradict

Comment: @jsbueno creio que seria uma resposta interessante a com o `BijectiveDict`  ;-) Como aparentemente ela não segue a rigor a ideia do multimapa, não vou por ela nessa minha resposta

Comment: é, o problema aqui é um pouco diferente. O BijectiveDict até tem suporte a multimapa, mas quando você começa ao contrário: varias chaves para um único valor. Mas nesse caso, o que o usuário pode querer fazer com o mapa é complicado - o mais simples é permitir só relações unívocas de 1:1 mesmo.   Chaves que apontam para o mesmo valor desmontam a relação anterior.

Answer (score 4):

Em um dicionário python, estrutura chave/valor. Para localizar a chaves de um dicionário através de seu valores existe um mecanismo nativo da linguagem chamado filtragem:

```
d = {'pizza': {'massa', 'ketchup'}, 'feijoada': {'feijão', 'linguiça'}}
 
entrada = 'feijão', 'linguiça'
entrada = set(entrada)
 
print(*filter(lambda k: entrada == d[k], d))
#feijoada
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/MlVgD4)</sup>

No exemplo acima a entrada é presumida como sendo uma [tupla](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) que então é convertida em um [set](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) para então ser comparada integralmente, através do operador `==`, com os valores de um dicionário cujo também são instancias de set.
A filtragem é realizada com a função embutida [`filter(função, iterável)`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#filter) que segundo a sua documentação constrói um iterador a partir dos elementos de um [*iterável*](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) para os quais a *função*  retorna verdadeiro. O *iterável* pode ser uma sequência, um contêiner que com suporte a iteração, ou um iterador.

Um fator facilitador seria a entrada ao invés da entrada ser uma tupla fosse um set, veja o mesmo exemplo acima caso a entrada á fosse uma instancia de set:

```python
d = {'pizza': {'massa', 'ketchup'}, 'feijoada': {'feijão', 'linguiça'}}

entrada = {'massa', 'ketchup'}

print(*filter(lambda k: entrada == d[k], d))
#pizza
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/zKblwd)</sup>

No exemplo abaixo é utilizado uma variação em que são permitidas comparações parciais utilizando o [operador de sets(conjuntos) `<=`](https://ideone.com/Sh7gge) que testa se cada elemento de um conjunto está contido em outro.

```python
d = {'pizza': {'massa', 'ketchup'}, 'feijoada': {'feijão', 'linguiça'}}
 
entrada = 'ketchup',
entrada = set(entrada)
 
print(*filter(lambda k: entrada <= d[k], d))
#pizza
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Sh7gge)</sup>

Mesmo exemplo acima porém aplicado em entrada que seja instancia de set:

```python
d = {'pizza': {'massa', 'ketchup'}, 'feijoada': {'feijão', 'linguiça'}}
 
entrada = {'ketchup'}
 
print(*filter(lambda k: entrada <= d[k], d))
#pizza
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/44IomT)</sup>

Comment: +1 - Bem mais simplificada e direta que a resposta aceita atualmente.

Comment: @CmteCardeal, valeu. Foi justamente esse o objetivo por trás dessa resposta, mostrar essa simplicidade que o python oferece ao trabalhar com estruturas de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo bem básico:

```
dicio = {'pizza': {'massa', 'ketchup'}, 'feijoada': {'feijão', 'linguiça'}}

def search(term):
    for k, v in dicio.items():
        if term in v:
            return k

    return None

print(search('massa'))
print(search('linguiça'))
```

Você só precisa adaptar o código pra pegar o input do usuário e efetuar a busca.

Comment: Eu recomendária usar Python 3 por padrão para responder dúvidas de Python. Python 2 já é menos usado, e para iniciantes faz menos sentido ainda dar dicas de python 2, já que eles deveriam mesmo estar aprendedendo a versão mais nova.

Comment: Entendido @jsbueno!

Answer (score -1):

```
valor = int(input("Insira o Valor: "))

meu_dicionario = {
    "Chave1": 1,
    "Chave2": 2,
    "Chave3": 3,
    "Chave4": 4,
    "Chave5": 5
}

for i in meu_dicionario.items():

    if valor == i[1]:

        chave = i[0]

print(chave)
```

Answer (score -4):

```
#current dict
key_value= {'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'c':'3'}
    
#new dict
value_key={}
    
for key, value in key_value.items():
    value_key[value] = key
        
value_key
```

There´s no other way to call a key through value, because a dict makes reference to key ever, being an one-way vector. So, the best method found is inverting its relationship becoming value to key, mutually.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua resposta? Caso prefira, você também pode acessar no [site em inglês do Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Carlos, mesmo que o dicionário não suporte diretamente essa operação, só ver as demais resposta que, com o que o dicionário fornece, você consegue ter essa informação. Por exemplo, a https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254610/64969 traz uma alternativa para resgatar a primeira chave que tem o valor desejado