# Passando uma lista de argumentos para uma consulta Jasper Reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Estou refazendo uns relatórios em Jasper Reports aqui da empresa. Estou migrando para ter um serviço de geração de relatórios agnóstico a estrutura da consulta SQL do relatório. Antes, o sistema conhecia profundamente como era feita tal consulta, mas isso esbarrou em algumas limitações que eu tenho.

Eu preciso fazer uma consulta com uma cláusula `IN`; por exemplo, saber os pedidos indo para os EUA, Itália e Alemanha.

> Um caso semelhante ao que a própria TIBCO colocou na [documentação de parâmetros em consultas](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/using-parameters-queries#jss-user-parameters_221620694_1026772)

Então minha consulta seria essa:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE SHIPCOUNTRY IN ('USA','Italy','Germany')
```

No JRXML, eu tinha a query desse jeito:

```xml
<parameter name="P_WHERE_CLAUSE" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT * FROM ORDERS $P!{P_WHERE_CLAUSE}
    ]]>
</queryString>
```

E na chamada ao relatório, o código Java antigo era assim:

```java
// public class RelatorioDownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {...
// ...
// protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
//    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { ...

String whereClause = " ";

String shippingCountries = request.getParameter("shipping");
if (shippingCountries  != null && !shippingCountries.isEmpty()) {
  whereClause = " WHERE SHIPCOUNTRY IN (" + shippingCountries + ")";
}

HashMap<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parametros.put("P_WHERE_CLAUSE", whereClause );
String templatePath = servletContext.getRealPath("shipping.jasper");
byte[] bytes;
try (Connection connection = getConnection()) {
  bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(templatePath, parametros, connection);
}
ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
servletOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
servletOutputStream.flush();
```

Só que esse modelo não me satisfaz. Eu construo a consulta (parcialmente) externa ao próprio JRXML e a execução dessa consulta com sucesso depende do chamador conhecer o relatório aprofundadamente a priori.

Como anteriormente dito, estou mudando para um serviço genérico de receber os parâmetros de um chamador abstrato e, então, montar o relatório. Estou fazendo esse serviço em Springboot, para outros relatórios ele faz o seguinte:

```java
@RestController
public class RelatorioController {

  @Autowired HikariDataSource dataSource;
  /**
   * CompileJasperRecursive é uma classe minha, ela possui dois métodos principais:
   * - getJasperReport: retorna um objeto JasperReport baseado no .jasper; não existindo o .jasper, compila-o chamando !compileIfShould"
   * - compileIfShould: verifica se deve gerar um novo .jasper baseado no .jrxml; também tenta procurar recursivamente por subrelatórios e compilá-los com "compileIfShould"
   *
   * não vejo esse cara como o problema, ele só faz isso
   */
  @Autowired CompileJasperRecursive compiler;

  @RequestMapping(path = "/{relat}.pdf", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/pdf")
  public void requisicaoPdf(@PathVariable("relat") String relat,
           @RequestParam Map<String, String> params,
           HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws JRException, SQLException, IOException {
    compilaRelatPDF(relat, params, resp.getOutputStream());
    resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + relat + ".pdf");
  }

  private void compilaRelatPDF(String relat, Map<String, String> params, OutputStream outputStream) throws JRException, SQLException, IOException {
    JasperReport jasperReport = compiler.getJasperReport("/path/relatorios/", relat + ".jrxml");
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.putAll(params);
    map.put("P_CAMINHO_SUB_RELAT", "/path/relatorios/"); // ocasional caminho dos subrelatórios
    
    JasperPrint print = fillReport(jasperReport, map);
    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputStream));

    SimplePdfReportConfiguration reportConfig = new SimplePdfReportConfiguration();
    reportConfig.setSizePageToContent(true);
    reportConfig.setForceLineBreakPolicy(false);

    SimplePdfExporterConfiguration exportConfig = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
    exportConfig.setMetadataAuthor("Jeff Coelho Quesado");
    exportConfig.setEncrypted(false);
    exportConfig.setAllowedPermissionsHint("PRINTING");

    exporter.setConfiguration(reportConfig);
    exporter.setConfiguration(exportConfig);
    exporter.exportReport();
  }
}
```

Nesse esquema, sem me preocupar de onde vem a requisição nem os parâmetros *a priori*, eu consigo montar todos os relatórios que não precisem de listas (passando os parâmetros como String). Mas não estou tranquilo ainda na parte de enviar essas listas.

Olhando a [documentação](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/using-parameters-queries#jss-user-parameters_221620694_1026772) e essa [questão aqui no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361177/64969), aparentemente a expansão `$X` faria o que eu preciso. A minha consulta ficaria desse jeito:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE $X{IN, SHIPCOUNTRY, myCountries}
```

Mas eu não sei como declarar os parâmetros no JRXML. No caso, ficaria algo mais ou menos assim?

```xml
<parameter name="myCountries" class="java.util.Collection"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE $X{IN, SHIPCOUNTRY, myCountries}
    ]]>
</queryString>
```

E como eu faria para tratar os dados do meu parâmetro a requisição? Gostaria de tratar o recebimento de `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` para evitar eventuais problemas com o SOP, mas ainda não testei passar vetores através desse formato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parte do `.jrxml` está correta. O uso da expansão `$X{}` foi feita de modo adequado. Mas a recepção do formulário não foi feita de maneira adequada.

No javadoc do [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) tem o seguinte:

> If the method parameter is `Map<String, String>` or `MultiValueMap<String, String>` and a parameter name is not specified, then the map parameter is populated with all request parameter names and values.

Em tradução livre:

> Se o parâmetro do método for `Map<String, String>` or `MultiValueMap<String, String>` e um nome de parâmetro  não é especificado, então o parâmetro de mapa será povoado com todos os e valores dos parâmetros da requisição.

Ao tentar usar o `Map`, o Spring Boot interpreta como um mapa normal e, portanto, só vai ter um único valor para a chave. É como se chegasse a requisição

```
myCountries=USA
myCountries=Italy
myCountries=Germany
```

E o Spring fizesse o seguinte:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("myCountries", "USA");
params.put("myCountries", "Italy");
params.put("myCountries", "Germany");
```

Então ao fazer `params.get("myCountries")` eu recebo como resposta `"Germany"`, não conseguindo portanto passar adequadamente os parâmetros da consulta.

Ao usar o `MultiValueMap<String, String>`, estamos trabalhando com um [multimapa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254612/64969), que no caso específico [é uma especialização da interface `Map<String,List<String>>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html). Então, se eu fosse repassar os argumentos diretamente para o Jasper trabalhar, teria de adaptar todos os meus parâmetros do relatório para serem `java.util.List`, mesmo que eu garanta que contenha no máximo uma única string.

Então, como tratar? Eu fiz uma convenção de que, se o meu argumento for multivalorado, então ele deve terminar com `[]`. Em HTML, seria algo assim:

```html
<input type="text" name="myCountries[]" placeholder="primeiro país"></input>
<input type="text" name="myCountries[]" placeholder="segundo país"></input>
```

Então, os valores seriam acrescentados *verbatim* nos parâmetros do Jasper removendo do nome do parâmetro os colchetes. Os demais valores seriam adicionados apenas o primeiro elemento:

```
params.forEach((k, v) -> {
  if (k.endsWith("[]")) {
    map.put(k.substring(0, k.length() - 2), v);
  } else {
    map.put(k, v.get(0));
  }
});
```

A ideia de fazer essa padronização de nomes veio depois de ler [esse artigo](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29587&seqNum=3); apesar de ser em PHP, acabei por usar essa padronização no final. Também vem a calhar que muitos dos artigos que aparecem no Google sobre enviar vetores através de formulários HTML é em PHP, então será menos trabalho para a equipe tentar internalizar isso.

Não foi feito nenhum tratamento especial para passar os argumentos como vetores posicionais (ou seja, nos elementos do formulário ter `name="myCountries[1]"`, `name="myCountries[2]"` etc) nem associativos (no caso de usar `name="form[address]"` ou `name="form[user]"`). Então, apesar de ser uma solução que trata da maior parte dos casos que eu me deparo na empresa, não é ainda a solução geral.

### Resumo

No `.jrxml`:

```xml
<parameter name="myCountries" class="java.util.Collection"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE $X{IN, SHIPCOUNTRY, myCountries}
    ]]>
</queryString>
```

No *form*:

```html
<input type="text" name="myCountries[]" placeholder="parâmtro multivalorado"></input>
<input type="text" name="myCountries[]" placeholder="parâmtro multivalorado"></input>
<input type="text" name="otherParam" placeholder="parâmtro escalar"></input>
```

No lado do servidor:

```
@RestController
public class RelatorioController {

  @Autowired HikariDataSource dataSource;
  @Autowired CompileJasperRecursive compiler;

  @RequestMapping(path = "/{relat}.pdf", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/pdf")
  public void requisicaoPdf(@PathVariable("relat") String relat,
           @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> params params,
           HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws JRException, SQLException, IOException {
    compilaRelatPDF(relat, params, resp.getOutputStream());
    resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + relat + ".pdf");
  }

  private void compilaRelatPDF(String relat, MultiValueMap<String, String> params, OutputStream outputStream) throws JRException, SQLException, IOException {
    JasperReport jasperReport = compiler.getJasperReport("/path/relatorios/", relat + ".jrxml");
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    params.forEach((k, v) -> {
      if (k.endsWith("[]")) {
        map.put(k.substring(0, k.length() - 2), v);
      } else {
        map.put(k, v.get(0));
      }
    });
    map.put("P_CAMINHO_SUB_RELAT", "/path/relatorios/"); // ocasional caminho dos subrelatórios

    JasperPrint print = fillReport(jasperReport, map);
    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputStream));

    SimplePdfReportConfiguration reportConfig = new SimplePdfReportConfiguration();
    reportConfig.setSizePageToContent(true);
    reportConfig.setForceLineBreakPolicy(false);

    SimplePdfExporterConfiguration exportConfig = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
    exportConfig.setMetadataAuthor("Jeff Coelho Quesado");
    exportConfig.setEncrypted(false);
    exportConfig.setAllowedPermissionsHint("PRINTING");

    exporter.setConfiguration(reportConfig);
    exporter.setConfiguration(exportConfig);
    exporter.exportReport();
  }
```

- Apenas vetores de valores escalares
- Não foi tratado enviar um valor em posição específica
- Não foi tratado vetor associativo