# Enviar Lista + Parâmetro para o Controller

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc

Estou tentando enviar uma lista e um parâmetro para o meu controller.
Meu controller está da seguinte forma:

```
@RequestMapping("/lista-receitas")
@ResponseBody
public String recebeLista(@RequestBody List<Receita> receitas, @RequestParam("nome") String nome){
    System.out.println("Receita: "+ nome);
    for(Receita r: receitas){
        System.out.println("ID: "+r.getId() +" Nome: "+ r.getNome());
    }

    return "Sucesso";
}
```

No meu método quero receber uma lista e um nome.

Meu JavaScritp está da seguinte forma:

```
function lista(){
    var lista=[];
    var Receita = new Object();
    var receitas = $('.receita');

    $(receitas).each(function(i){
        Receita = {
            id: $('#'+receitas[i].id).find("#id").text().trim(),
            nome: $('#'+receitas[i].id).find("#nome").text().trim()
         }
         lista.push(Receita);
   })
   return lista;
}


function enviarLista(){
    var receita = lista();
    var nome = "adm";
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:  'POST',
        //contentType: "application/json",
        url:   'lista-receitas',       
       data:{
            receita:JSON.stringify(receita),
            nome: nome
       },
      //dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){          
        alert(data);
      } 
  }); 
}
```

Se enviar apenas a lista e retirando o parâmetro **nome** do meu controller funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Tente mudar a ordem dos parâmetros do Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/lista-receitas")
@ResponseBody
public String recebeLista(@RequestParam("nome") String nome, @RequestBody List<Receita> receitas){
    System.out.println("Receita: "+ nome);
    for(Receita r: receitas){
        System.out.println("ID: "+r.getId() +" Nome: "+ r.getNome());
    }

    return "Sucesso";
}
```

Comment: Fiz a inversão, porém está dando erro 404 dizendo que o parâmetro nome não está sendo passado.

Comment: Tenta modificar a url no Ajax para:   'lista-receitas?nome='+nome,

Comment: Agora sim funcionou hein, muito obrigado!! Você o pqe de não funcionar enviar a lista e o parâmetro juntos?

Comment: @DanielMoura, em tese, esse envio de informações está, semanticamente, uma bagunça. Quando você envio o parâmetro via `POST` tradicional, ele irá dentro do `RequestBody`, então acaba que mistura as coisas. A solução do renanzin foi enviar esse parâmetro pelo URL (tradicionalmente, parâmetro de `GET`; também conhecido como `QueryParam`). Particularmente acho bagunçado usar assim, preferiria criar uma parametrização através do `PATH`, não dos `QueryParam`...

Comment: @DanielMoura, eu uso essa parametrização [nessa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/291236/64969); fica algo assim: `@RequestMapping(path = "/{relat}.pdf", ...)
  public void requisicaoPdf(@PathVariable("relat") String relat ...)`; o argumento é tratado como a parte do modelo da `PATH` que está entre chaves, e o parâmetro é indicado pela anotação `@PathVariable`

Comment: Irei testar essa outra forma.

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver usando spring vc pode usar a estas sintax

```
@RequestMapping(value = "lista-receitas",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
```

ou

```
@PostMapping("lista-receitas")
```