# Como passar parâmetros para cláusulas IN no JasperReports?

Tags: java, sql, jasper-reports, ireport

Estou com uma duvida na passagem de um parâmetro no Ireport.
Preciso passar como parâmetro uma lista.

Exemplo:
No código SQL a query fica assim:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE COD IN (1,2,3,4)
```

No Ireport com a passagem do parametro estou tentando fazer dessa forma:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE COD IN ($P{CODIGO})
```

E no parâmetro da janela que se abre passo os dados (1,2,3). Porém, desta forma não esta dando certo.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/291236/64969

Comment: Inclusive se desejar saber como faço a compilação dinâmica dos relatórios independente do ireport ou do jaspersoft-studio, pode abrir uma pergunta e me mencionar aqui para eu ser notificado

Answer (score 3):

A sintaxe para lidar com cláusulas `IN` conforme a [documentação da Jaspersoft](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v71/using-parameters-queries-0#jss-user-parameters_221620694_1025261) é `$X{IN, NOME_DA_COLUNA, nomeDoParametro}`. No seu caso:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE $X{IN, COD, codigos}
```

`codigos` deve ser uma `List`, `Collection` ou *array*.

Alternativamente você pode utilizar um *placeholder* `$P!{placeholder}`. Porém, essa solução é menos desejável, entre outras coisas, por ser vulnerável a ataques de *SQL Injection*:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE COD IN ( $P!{codigos} )
```

Nesse caso, `codigos` é uma String com os códigos separados por vírgula.

Comment: Eu sou contra a estratégia da expansão `$P!` por, além dos problemas já citados, ele não funciona tão bem para a ausência de valores. Na expansão do `$X{IN, ...}`, quando não há valores, o Jasper coloca `1=1` no lugar da expressão, o que então mantém a integridade da estrutura da consulta. Eu também sou contra o `eval` desnecessário, ele é mais maléfico que o `goto`

Comment: Anthony, obrigado pela resposta. Vamos lá.
Estou com alguma duvidas ainda.

Utilizando o  `WHERE $X{IN, COD, codigos}` como eu crio a lista codigos no Ireport?

Vi no link que compartilhou que você cria atraves do <parameter>, porem ainda esta confuso pra mim.

Comment: Oi Jorge, é isso mesmo. Você cria códigos como qualquer outro Parâmetro na barra lateral (e.g., clique com o botão direito e em *Add parameter*). A única coisa que você tem que fazer para que o parâmetro funcione é mudar a classe de `String` para `Collection` ou algum dos outros tipos sugeridos acima.

Comment: Anthony,
Abaixo esta parte do meu WHERE:

`AND I.CODPROD = PR.CODPROD
$X{IN,  C.CODTIPOPER , TOP} 
AND C.STATUSNOTA = 'L'`

Estou fazendo da maneira acima e o ireport esta informando que meu codigo esta errado.

Me desculpe a insistência, porem essa forma de passagem de parâmetros é nova para mim.