# Buscar um valor dentro de um array de dicionários

Tags: python

Olá, estou fazendo o seguinte em python:

Criei um array de dicionários e gostaria de pesquisar dentro deste array se uma determinada palavra existe.

Ex:

```
palavra1 = {'palavra': 'sim', 'positivo': 0}
palavra2 = {'palavra': 'não', positivo: 0}
palavras = [palavra1, palavra2]
```

Gostaria de pesquisar se a palavra 'sim' está dentro de 'palavras'.
Como faço isso?

Pensei em usar o método palavras.index(), mas preciso usar também o método get do dicionário para verificar o valor de 'palavra', como faria isso?

Comment: Você não quer buscar pela chave? Quer buscar pelo valor? Se sim, a ideia é esta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254612/64969, mas a implementação precisaria de uns ajustes para se adequar à lista de dicionários

Comment: Quero buscar pelo valor, porque a chave 'palavra' vai ser sempre a mesma... O que eu quero fazer no final das contas seria contabilizar o número de positivos e negativos em uma lista de palavras que se repetem. Aí o que eu quero fazer mesmo é percorrer essa lista. Caso a palavra exista, contabilizar +1 em positivo ou negativo, dependendo da sua classificação em uma outra estrutura..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode calcular a quantidade de vezes que a palavra `sim` aparece dentro da sua lista de dicionários, veja só:

```
palavra1 = {'palavra': 'sim', 'positivo': 0}
palavra2 = {'palavra': 'não', 'positivo': 0}
palavras = [ palavra1, palavra2 ]

n = sum([ d["palavra"] == "sim" for d in palavras ])

print( n )
```

Ou:

```
palavra1 = {'palavra': 'sim', 'positivo': 0}
palavra2 = {'palavra': 'não', 'positivo': 0}
palavras = [ palavra1, palavra2 ]

n = len([ d for d in palavras if d["palavra"] == "sim" ])

print( n )
```

Saída:

```
1
```

Comment: Apesar da resposta do Anderson fazer muito sentido, acabei utilizando esta aqui para contabilizar quantas vezes aparece. Caso seja zero, significa que a palavra não existe na lista. Obrigado

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar a função `filter`:

```
resultado = filter(lambda termo: termo['palavra'] == 'sim', palavras)
```

O resultado será um objeto iterável (gerador) com todos os dicionários que possuem `'palavra'` igual à `'sim'`.

Além disso, você pode utilizar uma *list comprehension*:

```
resultado = [termo for termo in palavras if termo['palavra'] == 'sim']
```

Que pode ficar mais legível no código. Para definir um gerador da mesma forma, basta substituir os colchetes por parenteses:

```
resultado = (termo for termo in palavras if termo['palavra'] == 'sim')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/BubblyClearComputergraphics) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/xPdEBP) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/097d69852407ca02871d8c7aa4cb26fd)</sup>

Comment: Obrigado, Anderson, utilizei a list comprehension, era por aí mesmo a resposta.