# Obter a quantidade de dígitos em um número

Tags: python, matemática

Me pediram para me fazer um algoritmo em Python para saber a quantidade de dígitos em um número, existe um jeito de fazer sem a manipulação de *strings*?

```
def achaTamanho(x):
    a = str(x)
    if len(a) > 1:
        if a[0] == '0':
            return len(a) - 1
        else:
            return len(a)
    return len(a)


num = int(input("Digite um número: "))
print(achaTamanho(num))
```

Comment: Logaritmo na base 10

Comment: Detalhes: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/239881/64969

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 7):

Sempre é melhor fazer com matemática (bom, parece que Python nem tanto, ainda é bom assim, mas ela é lenta quase igualmente). Fiz um usar função matemática pronta e outro sem precisar de nenhum módulo. Poderia simplificar fazendo a divisão, mas divisão custa mais caro que multiplicação.

```
import math 

def achaTamanho(numero):
    numero = abs(int(numero))
    if numero < 2:
        return 1
    count = 0
    valor = 1
    while valor <= numero:
        valor *= 10
        count += 1
    return count

def achaTamanho2(numero):
    numero = abs(int(numero))
    return (1 if numero == 0 else math.floor(math.log10(numero)) + 1)
    
print(achaTamanho(0))
print(achaTamanho(1))
print(achaTamanho(2))
print(achaTamanho(123))
print(achaTamanho(1000))
print(achaTamanho(-1))
print(achaTamanho(-23))
print(achaTamanho(45678))
print(achaTamanho(9999))
print ("")
print(achaTamanho2(0))
print(achaTamanho2(1))
print(achaTamanho2(2))
print(achaTamanho2(123))
print(achaTamanho2(1000))
print(achaTamanho2(-1))
print(achaTamanho2(-23))
print(achaTamanho2(45678))
print(achaTamanho2(9999))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/WBk3E4). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kmctvruf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/CountDigits.py).

Comment: Para o futuro leitor: caso interesse saber quantos dígitos são necessários na base `XYZ`, troque `valor *= 10` por `valor *= XYZ` e `math.log10(numero)` por `math.log(numero, XYZ)`

Comment: Eu acho que você normalizou duas vezes o número dentro do `math.log10`: uma logo no começo de `achaTamanho2` e outra na chamada de `math.log10`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado é verdade ;)

Comment: Cuidado com isso de "divisão custa mais caro que multiplicação", principalmente em Python -" . Faz décadas - literalmente, que em baixo nível - no tempo da linguagem de máquina, divisão e multiplicação são equivalentes - e são completadas por circuitos dedicados em um único ciclo de clock. Por outro lado, linguagens como Python são tão abstraídas desse baixo nível - em Python, cada novo valor numérico é um objeto do tipo "int" que tem que ser construído, por exemplo, que esse tempo do hardware não tem o menor sentido mesmo que a divisão fosse 10 vezes mais cara que uma multiplicação.

Comment: @jsbueno não nos últimos testes que eu fiz há poucos anos. Pelo menos em inteiros. E sem considerar otimizações que o compilador possa fazer para eliminar a divisão. Você está dizendo que Python é altamente ineficiente que mesmo que a divisão custe muito mais caro, no todo importa pouco? Isto eu até acredito.

Comment: Isso - é trivial que para computações numéricas intensivas, em Python, você deve usar uma biblioteca qeu faça as operações em código nativo, como o numpy.

Para calcular a quantidade de dígitos de um único número, é irrelevante. A não ser que fosse um web-service para responder umas 50000 requisições desse tipo por segundo.

Comment: agora, fiquei curiso sobre isso dos inteiros - como você fez esses testes? tem em algum lugar? Por que pra inteiros em C ou outro código nativo, o tempo de multiplicação e divisão deveria ser o mesmo (a divisão deve usar mais recursos em hardware, mas esses recursos estão lá ,"soldados" no chip)

Comment: @jsbueno faz tempo que fiz, mas é teste bem trivial,. Eu não disse que a diferença é de 10x, não é grande, mas a multiplicação é melhor que a divisão, só disse isso.

Comment: sim - mas na "minha conta", ambas deveriam custar 1 ciclo de clock. mas deve ser alguma coisa em volta, seja no microcódigo, seja no código do compilador, pra pegar exceções da divisão então.

Comment: Não levei em consideração memória e CPU, pq achei que seria um exagero, mas em operações por segundo (aproximado) ambos métodos foram semelhantes (apesar de depender muito da máquina que está executando): https://repl.it/@inphinit/benchmark-size-digits -- No Windows, em uma máquina com 16GB RAM todos testes foram quase iguais, o que variava a cada teste, então em questão de operações por segundo nenhuma foi aparentemente vantajosa. PS: gostei mais da primeira, que usou as casas "checando" :) +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento no repl.it nem dá pra confiar, cada execução dá um número completamente diferente, mas acredito em você, acho que é o que eu disse, Python é tão ruim de performance que tudo fica ruim. É aquela estória que eu falo quando Clipper executava o Codeblock muito mais rápido que a macro pra obter o mesmo resultado. Aí uma empresa fez sua versão do Clipper e eliminou essa diferença entre eles,agora o Codeblock é tão lento quanto a macro :D Enquanto isso a comunidade fez sua versão do Clipper (Harbour) e criou uma forma da macro (ou algo equivalente) ficar quase tão rápido qto o CB

Answer (score -3):

```
def achaTamanho(x): 
    return (len(str(x)))
num = int(input("Digite um número: "))
print(achaTamanho(num))
```

Answer (score -5):

Cara, eu fiz sem usar "if" ou expressão matemática, apenas tratando os números como string e usando o parâmetro "len".

```
def contador(n):
    contagem = len(n)
    return contagem
n = str(input('Informe um numero inteiro: '))
print(contador(n))
```

Comment: Que é a mesma "solução" das outras respostas postadas já faz meses. Realço este detalhe da pergunta: _Me pediram para me fazer um algoritmo em Python para saber a quantidade de dígitos em um número, existe um jeito de fazer **sem a manipulação de strings?**_