# Contar quantas ocorrências de um número há em outro, de forma recursiva

Tags: python, recursão

Utilizando a linguagem Python, escreva uma função recursiva que determine quantas vezes um número `k` de 2 dígitos ocorre em um número natural `n`. Por exemplo, o numero 21 ocorre duas vezes em 2135219877.

O problema do meu código é que ele só conta o numero de dois dígitos quando só há dois dígitos no numero a ser avaliado. Como posso arrumar isso?

```
def verifica(num,c,aux):
    if num==0:
        return c
    
    else:
        if aux==(num//10):
            c+=1
            num=num//10
            return verifica(num,c,aux)
        else:            
            num=num//10
            return verifica(num,c,aux)
    print('numero',aux,'encontrado',c,'vezes')

c=0    
num=int(input('digite um numero: '))
aux=int(input('digite o numero que procura: '))
verifica(num,c,aux)
print('encontrei',aux,c,'vezes.')
```

Comment: Não sei se entende sua lógica. No seu exemplo - 2135219877 - o número 21 não ocorre apenas 2 vezes?

Comment: corrigido, é verdade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas para constar, recursão não é a forma mais eficiente de resolver este problema. Dito isso, vamos à solução.

---

Um dos problemas da sua função é que eu posso chamá-la assim: `verifica(num, -190, aux)` e pronto, já baguncei a contagem, pois o contador começará em -190. Se o contador deve sempre começar em zero, ele não deveria ser um parâmetro.

A ideia básica do algoritmo é:

- comparo os 2 últimos algarismos do número `n`, se forem iguais a `k`, incremento o contador
- divido `n` por 10 (eliminando assim o último dígito) e continuo a contagem
- se `n` chegar a zero, fim do algoritmo

Assumindo que o número `k` sempre tem 2 dígitos (já que isso não é verificado), ficaria assim:

```
def verifica(n, k):
    if n == 0:
        return 0

    if n % 100 == k:
        c = 1
    else:
        c = 0
    return c + verifica(n // 10, k)

n, k = 2135219877, 21
print(f'O número {k} ocorre {verifica(n, k)} vezes no número {n}')
```

Como um `return` retorna o valor e encerra a execução da função, o bloco `else` no primeiro `if` é desnecessário. Também tirei o `print` de dentro da função, pois ela só deveria retornar o valor, e quem a chama que faça o que quiser com ele (inclusive imprimir, se for o caso). Sem contar que, por ser recursiva, são feitas várias chamadas (uma para cada dígito de `n`) e aí seriam impressas várias mensagens, desnecessariamente.

Para obter os 2 últimos dígitos de `n`, basta pegar o resto da divisão por 100, usando o operador `%`. Depois eu vejo se é igual a `k`, e somo 1 se for o caso.

Depois, esse valor é somado com o resultado da contagem no restante do número (o resultado da divisão de `n` por 10).

Vale lembrar que `verifica(111, 11)` retorna `2`, pois os 2 últimos dígitos de 111 são 11, e depois eu divido 111 por 10, resultando em 11, o que contabiliza outra ocorrência de 11.

---

Como já dito, o algoritmo funciona apenas se `k` tiver exatamente 2 dígitos (ou se for menor que 10, por exemplo, se `n` for `10303` e `k` for `3`, a contagem contabiliza `2`).

Mas se a ideia é deixar o algoritmo mais "genérico", você pode verificar a [quantidade de dígitos de `k`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/271954/112052) e usar esse valor no cálculo - de forma geral, se `k` tiver `x` dígitos, basta pegar o resto da divisão por 10<sup>x</sup>.

Outro detalhe é que não precisa ir até `n` ser igual a zero. Se `n` for menor que `k`, já posso parar a verificação, pois a partir daí não terá mais nenhuma ocorrência:

```
import math

def qtd_digitos(numero):
    numero = abs(int(numero))
    return (1 if numero == 0 else math.floor(math.log10(numero)) + 1)

def verifica(n, k):
    if n < k:
        return 0
    if n % (10 ** qtd_digitos(k)) == k:
        c = 1
    else:
        c = 0
    return c + verifica(n // 10, k)
```

---

Lembrando que a solução recursiva não é a ideal para este caso. Isso porque muitas chamadas recursivas podem causar [um estouro de pilha](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3323001) se a quantidade de chamadas for suficientemente grande.

Nesse caso, um *loop* simples já resolve. Além disso, falta verificar alguns *corner cases*, quando ambos os valores são zero, ou quando somente `k` é zero:

```
import math

def qtd_digitos(numero):
    numero = abs(int(numero))
    return (1 if numero == 0 else math.floor(math.log10(numero)) + 1)

def verifica(n, k):
    if n == 0 and k == 0:
        return 1
    c = 0
    qtd = qtd_digitos(k)
    while (k == 0 and n > k) or (k != 0 and n >= k):
        if n % (10 ** qtd) == k:
            c += 1
        n //=10
    return c

print(verifica(0, 0)) # 1
print(verifica(100, 0)) # 2
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo! Do pouco que eu entendo de programação eu também concordo que essa não é a forma mais eficiente de resolver esse problemas mas fazer o que né, outra solução não é aceita...

Comment: @Eliasteixeira Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.

Comment: Me desculpe pelo inconveniente, acabei saindo da frente do computador antes de aceitar a resposta. Grato pela ajuda!