# Como faço para contar quantos dígitos, possui um resultado de uma operação?

Tags: python

Tenho uma operação que resulta em um número qualquer.

Exemplo:

> > > 25**7 = 6103515625

**O resultado tem 10 dígitos.**

quero executar a contagem automática da quantidade de dígitos do resultado em qualquer operação.

Comment: O código apresentado na resposta é ineficiente e não funciona com números negativos. Se quer calcular de forma rápida a quantidade de dígitos de um inteiro na base 10 use a fórmula `floor(log10(abs(n))+1)`. Veja o exemplo: https://ideone.com/vVXmSu

Comment: Complementando o @AugustoVasques, `log(a ** b)` é igual a `b * log(a)`, ou seja, pra esse caso nem precisa fazer a conta (isso pode fazer diferença se os números começam a ficar muito grandes - e nesse caso a solução abaixo se torna ainda mais ineficiente). Indo além, dá pra aproveitar as propriedades dos logaritmos pra simplificar outras operações também, como multiplicação e divisão. Por fim, segue um link com respostas melhores: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271949/112052

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Utilize a função nativa `len()`.

Primeiro transforme o resultado de Inteiro para String, com `str()`, e chame a função `len()` para sua variável resultado, como por exemplo:

```
resultado =  str(25**7)
 
qtdNumeros = len(resultado)
```

Comment: `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`

Comment: Corrigido resposta, por descuido acabei esquecendo desta parte.