# Como utilizar Stream.reduce() de forma apropriada

Tags: java, stream

Meu problema: Tenho um ArrayList do tipo de Rotas (primeiro valor é o nome da cidade, segundo valor é a cidade destino e o terceiro valor a distancia),
quero criar um novo mapa organizando essas rotas em suas devidas cidades origem.

exemplo:

tenho uma lista de rotas assim = `[AB6, AE4, BA6, BC2, BD4, CB3, CD1, CE7, BD8, EB5, ED7]`

e o mapa final que eu quero seria `{A=[AB6, AE4], B=[BA6 , BC2, BD4, BD8], C=[CB3, CD1, CE7]}`

Minha lista de rotas:

```
List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<Route>();
            routes.add(new Route("A","B",6));
            routes.add(new Route("A","E",4));
            routes.add(new Route("B","A",6));
            routes.add(new Route("B","C",2));
            routes.add(new Route("B","D",4));
            routes.add(new Route("C","B",3));
            routes.add(new Route("C","D",1));
            routes.add(new Route("C","E",7));
            routes.add(new Route("B","D",8));
            routes.add(new Route("E","B",5));
            routes.add(new Route("E","D",7));


            Stream data = Stream.of(routes);
```

dessa lista que possuo tentei fazer um reduce, onde eu passo um mapa vazio e de acordo com a função que eu passei vou preenchendo este mapa, mas não to conseguindo andar...

```
data.reduce(new HashMap<String,List<Route>> (), (map, current) -> {
    if (map.containsValue(current.getSource()/* seria o primeiro valor da rota */)) {
                map.get(current.getSource()).add(current);
    } else {
                List<Route> x = new ArrayList<>();
                x.add(current);
                map.put(current.getSource(),x);
    }
return map;
});
```

isso é o que eu pensei que conseguiria fazer, mas não consegui... 
**Minha pergunta é**:  Estou errando em utilizar o Reduce? ou é  por Reduce mesmo só estou me perdendo na lógica?

Comment: Eu acho que já tem um `Collector` que faça isso...

Comment: tem chute de algum? to com dificuldade de qual utilizar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acredito que o que você precisa é o [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-). Aproveitando sua lista `routes` e passando como critério de agrupamento uma propriedade da classe `Route`, no caso, `getOrigem()`:

```
Map<String, List<Route>> rotasAgrupadas = routes.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Route::getOrigem);
```

Comment: Deu certo, Obrigado !!!! tava me tirando o sono já rs

Comment: Se te ajudou, marque a resposta como correta, para ajudar outros colegas no futuro.

Comment: `Collectors.groupingBy(Route::getOrigem)` é um pouco mais simples.

Comment: @VictorStafusa valeu pela dica. Editado na resposta.

Answer (score 5):

A [resposta aceita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/305063/64969) já responde o que é importante saber sobre a questão. Porém, ainda senti uma brecha solta: e como seria usando `reduce`?

## Preliminares

Para começar, precisamos entender quais são os tipos possíveis de `reduce`; os tipos são os seguintes (na frente eu pus um *alias* para eu poder me referir ao longo do texto):

- **op-reduce**: [`Optional<T> reduce(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(java.util.function.BinaryOperator))
- **id-merge**: [`T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(T,java.util.function.BinaryOperator))
- **map-merge**:  [`U reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U, ? extends super T, U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(U,java.util.function.BiFunction,java.util.function.BinaryOperator))

### op-reduce

Essa redução é útil para quando não se há um valor neutro/identitade previamente conhecido. De modo geral, ele é idêntico ao comportamento de **id-merge**, exceto em um caso especial: no caso do conjunto vazio. Para o caso geral, eu prefiro explicar dentro do corpo da outra redução.

Quando o conjunto de entrada é vazio, o **op-reduce** retorna `Optional.empty()`, caso contrário retornará um `Optional` com o valor adequado. Você pode tratar o resultado do modo tradicional do `Optional`:

```
Stream<X> fluxo = ...;
Optional<X> reducao = fluxo.reduce((x1, x2) -> operacaoCombinaX(x1, x2));
reducao.ifPresentOrElse(x -> System.out.println("A redução é " + x), () -> System.out.println("Fluxo vazio =P");
```

### id-merge

Aqui, a redução garante que pelo menos haja o elemento neutro. Um elemento `id` é considerado neutro se, para a operação `op`, `op(id, x) ==> x`, qualquer que seja `x`.

Essa redução sempre retornará um valor, nem que seja a identidade. Ele pode ser entendido de diversas maneiras:

```
T respostaReducao = identity;
for (T valorNovo: valoresDaStream) {
  respostaReducao = accumulator(respostaReducao, valorNovo);
}
```

Mas essa operação não precisa ser linear. Se você tiver 6 elementos e deseja reduzi-los todos, também poderia fazer em paralelo:

```
x1---x2  x3---x4  id---x5  id---x6
   |        |        |        |
   x7-------x8       x5-------x6
        |                 |
        x9----------------xa
                 |
                 xb
```

Nessa árvore de operações, cada barra vertical `|` é a aplicação da função `accumulate` para os argumentos passados.

As operações com a identidade `id` são tautológicas, mas as coloquei por ilustração, para todas as operações ficarem com o mesmo nível de profundidade.

### map-merge

Esse mapeamento não retornará o mesmo tipo do tipo passado. Ele pode ser pensado como uma espécie de mapeamento seguido de redução. Os seguintes códigos são mais ou menos equivalentes:

```
Stream<X> fluxo = ...;
U id = ...;
BiFunction<U, T, U> map2u = ...;
BinaryOperator<U> merge = ...;

// usando diretamente a redução map-merge
U reducaoMapMerge = fluxo.reduce(id, map2u, merge);

// fazendo o mapeamento para U e usando id-merge
U reducaoIdMerge = fluxo.map(map2u).reduce(id, merge);

// fazendo o mapeamento para U e usando op-reduce, pegando identidade caso vazio
U reducaoOpReduce = fluxo.map(map2u).reduce(merge).orElse(id);
```

## Qual o tipo de redução adequada para a questão?

A primeira coisa a se observar é o que se tem e o que se pretende retornar.

- **o que se tem**? um fluxo de `Route`
- **o que se pretende retornar**? um [multimapa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240048/64969) da chave para todas as `Route`s dessa chave

Como o tipo de retorno obtido é diferente do tipo de entrada, então vou para a estratégia do **map-reduce**. Agora, preciso estabelecer quem é o elemento neutro e quais são as funções:

- **quem é *id***? `new HashMap<String, List<Route>>()`
  no caso, poderíamos usar o operador diamante para tratar isso mais elegantemente `new HashMap<>()`, mas quis deixar explícito ali quais os tipos usados
- **quem é *accumulate***? o método [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) parece adequado, só preciso antes transformar a nova `Route` passada em um `List<Route>` antes; ou então fazer a verificação se a chave existe e inserir no final da lista:

  ```
  // usando o Map.merge
  (hm, route) -> {
    List<Route> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    lista.add(route);
    hm.merge(route.getSource(), lista, (l1, l2) -> { l1.addAll(l2), return l1; });
    return hm;
  };

  // inspecionando se já existe a lista e, caso contrário, criando-a

  (hm, route) -> {
    List<Route> lista = hm.getOrDefault(route.getSource(), new ArrayList<>());
    lista.add(route);
    hm.putIfAbsent(route.getSource(), lista);
    return hm;
  };
  ```
- **quem é *combine***? esse método deve pegar dois `Map`s e combiná-los; posso iterar nas chaves do segundo `Map` e chamar algo para misturar as duas listas:

  ```
  (hm1, hm2) -> {
    hm2.forEach( (k, listaRoutes) -> {
      List<Route> listaOriginal = hm1.get(k);
      if (listaOriginal == null) {
        hm1.put(k, listsRoutes);
      } else {
        listaOriginal.addAll(listaRoutes);
      }
    });
    return hm1;
  };
  ```

## Como fica o código?

Fica mais ou menos assim, nesse caso:

```
Stream<Route> fluxo = ...;
Map<String, List<Route>> mapeamento =
    fluxo.reduce(new HashMap<>(),
        /* accumulate */
        (hm, route) -> {
          List<Route> lista = hm.getOrDefault(route.getSource(), new ArrayList<>());
          lista.add(route);
          hm.putIfAbsent(route.getSource(), lista);
          return hm;
        },
        /* combine */
        (hm1, hm2) -> {
          hm2.forEach( (k, listaRoutes) -> {
            List<Route> listaOriginal = hm1.get(k);
            if (listaOriginal == null) {
              hm1.put(k, listsRoutes);
            } else {
              listaOriginal.addAll(listaRoutes);
            }
          });
          return hm1;
        }
);
```

### Jabá: `totalcross-functional-toolbox`

O TotalCross por si só não dá o suporte necessário para `stream`s do Java 8. Como o TotalCross praticamente não fornece suporte ao Java 8 (com exceções através do [`retrolambda`](https://gitlab.com/totalcross/TotalCross/wikis/Retrolambda) e de algumas interfaces funcionais (mas [não todas](https://gitlab.com/totalcross/TotalCross/issues/184) corretamente)), e tive a necessidade de usar `stream` no meu projeto, então implementei algo semelhante ao uso de `stream`s.

Com isso, surgiu o projeto [`totalcross-functional-toolbox`](https://gitlab.com/geosales-open-source/totalcross-functional-toolbox/), criado aqui na empresa e disponibilizado sob a licença MIT, que entre outras coisas com a pegada mais funcional também se preocupou em implementar o que precisamos usar de `Stream` e de `Optional`.

Assim, precisei implementar o [`Collectors.groupingBy(Function<T, K> keyExtractor)`](https://gitlab.com/geosales-open-source/totalcross-functional-toolbox/blob/57f4d5f4f53603fe956271b9d17b8a4555e64911/src/main/java/br/com/softsite/toolbox/stream/Collectors.java#L171-173). Basicamente, uma implementação que funciona é fazer o `Collectors.groupingBy` chamar o `Collectors.toMap` transformando cada elemento individual numa lista mutável de um elemento ([`CollectionUtils::getSingletonList`](https://gitlab.com/geosales-open-source/totalcross-functional-toolbox/blob/57f4d5f4f53603fe956271b9d17b8a4555e64911/src/main/java/br/com/softsite/toolbox/CollectionUtils.java#L43-47)) e um método para concatenar duas listas ([`CollectionUtils::addAll`](https://gitlab.com/geosales-open-source/totalcross-functional-toolbox/blob/57f4d5f4f53603fe956271b9d17b8a4555e64911/src/main/java/br/com/softsite/toolbox/CollectionUtils.java#L65-69)).

Mais precisamente? Quando implementei o `Collectors.groupingBy`, fiz uma versão muito parecida do `reduce` que aqui foi feito.

Comment: Obrigado mesmo Jefferson, a outra resposta me atendeu, mas gostei muito da sua, e o legal é que fica de conhecimento pro próximo. Parabéns.

Comment: @LuisFelipe minha ideia foi para ficar de referência de leitura. Eu realmente acredito que a mais correta é a do StatelessDev, eu teria respondido assim. Mas fui lento, então peguei me perguntando "e se alguém parar nessa pergunta com essa necessidade do título?", daí resolvi escrever isto daqui.