# Em um map/reduce no Java, a operação de acumulação deve gerar um novo objeto? Ou posso aproveitar o antigo?

Tags: java, java-8, paralelismo

Eu tenho uma aplicação que cria diversos objetos em cima de um `stream` de funções. E então eu coleto todos esses objetos gerados em um acumulador. Por exemplo, se eu gerasse strings e acumulasse em uma lista, faria uma coisa assim:

```
List<Function<T, String>> funcoes = /* inicializa com as diversas funções */;

T objetoSobProcessamento = /* parâmetro arbitrário */
List<String> retornoProcessamento = funcoes.stream().map(f -> f.apply(objetoSobProcessamento))
  .reduce(new ArrayList<>(), (listaAcumulada, novoValor) -> {
            listaAcumulada.add(novoValor);
            return listaAcumulada;
          }, (l1, l2) -> {
            l1.addAll(l2);
            return l1;
          });
```

> O caso real é com outros objetos, ligeiramente mais complexos, mas segue o mesmo espírito

Ao olhar as [possíveis operações de `reduce` em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/306175/64969), me veio uma dúvida sobre a paralelização da operação de redução, no caso genérico. Olhar [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195246/64969) me deixou com a impressão de que essa operação de `reduce` deveria ser sequencial, não paralelizável.

Então, minha pergunta é:

- na operação de acumulação, para aproveitar ao máximo o paralelismo, devo produzir *sempre* um objeto novo? ou devo *sempre* reaproveitar o objeto? ou deveria apenas evitar reusar o objeto `identidade`, gerando novos objetos quando se acumula a primeira vez e reaproveitando esse novo elemento gerado nas conseguintes?

Eu sei que a operação de combinação/*merge* dos objetos obtidos é perfeitamente paralelizável se e somente se os argumentos passados a ela sejam únicos, como no caso ilustrado abaixo:

```
t1--A--ui  t2--A--ui  t3--A--ui  t4--A--ui
    |          |          |          |
    u1----M----u2         u3----M----u4
          |                     |
          u5---------M----------u6
                     |
                     u7
```

Onde `A` é uma operação de acumulação, `M` é uma operação de de *merge*, `t?` é um objeto do tipo da entrada `T`, `u?` é um objeto do tipo do retorno `U` e `ui` é o objeto de identidade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bem, você não disse o que você usa como a classe `T` e nem o que são essas funções que operam sobre ela para produzir `String`s. Então vou inventar uma classe para isso:

```
class Colorido {
    private void complica() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 50));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Ignora.
        }
    }
    public String getVermelho() { complica(); return "vermelho"; }
    public String getLaranja()  { complica(); return "laranja";  }
    public String getAmarelo()  { complica(); return "amarelo";  }
    public String getLima()     { complica(); return "lima";     }
    public String getVerde()    { complica(); return "verde";    }
    public String getCiano()    { complica(); return "ciano";    }
    public String getAzul()     { complica(); return "azul";     }
    public String getVioleta()  { complica(); return "violeta";  }
    public String getRosa()     { complica(); return "rosa";     }
    public String getRoxo()     { complica(); return "roxo";     }
    public String getBranco()   { complica(); return "branco";   }
    public String getPreto()    { complica(); return "preto";    }
    public String getMarrom()   { complica(); return "marrom";   }
    public String getOliva()    { complica(); return "oliva";    }
    public String getBege()     { complica(); return "bege";     }
    public String getCinza()    { complica(); return "cinza";    }
    public static List<Function<Colorido, String>> funcoes() {
        return Arrays.asList(
            Colorido::getVermelho, Colorido::getLaranja, Colorido::getAmarelo, Colorido::getLima,
            Colorido::getVerde, Colorido::getCiano, Colorido::getAzul, Colorido::getVioleta,
            Colorido::getRosa, Colorido::getRoxo, Colorido::getBranco, Colorido::getPreto,
            Colorido::getMarrom, Colorido::getOliva, Colorido::getBege, Colorido::getCinza
        );
    }
}
```

Esta é decerto uma classe bem boba. No entanto, observe que o método `funcoes` vai devolver uma lista com 16 funções que operam sobre o objeto. Cada função retorna o nome de uma cor diferente, mas todas elas vão demorar algum tempinho para fazer isso graças ao `Thread.sleep` de tempo aleatório dentro do método `complica`. Afinal de contas, se queremos testar paralelismo, é importante que as threads não executem de forma demasiadamente rápida para evitarmos que uma comece quando a outra já terminou.

Então, vamos testar o map-reduce que você colocou na pergunta:

```
public static <T> List<String> mapReduceSequencial(
    List<Function<T, String>> funcoes, // inicializa com as diversas funções
    T objetoSobProcessamento) // parâmetro arbitrário
{
    List<String> retornoProcessamento = funcoes
            .stream()
            .map(f -> f.apply(objetoSobProcessamento))
            .reduce(new ArrayList<>(), (listaAcumulada, novoValor) -> {
                listaAcumulada.add(novoValor);
                return listaAcumulada;
            }, (l1, l2) -> {
                l1.addAll(l2);
                return l1;
            });
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(retornoProcessamento);
}
```

Ele é invocado assim:

```
System.out.println(mapReduceSequencial(Colorido.funcoes(), new Colorido()));
```

Eis a saída (acrescentei a quebra de linha só para facilitar a leitura):

```
[vermelho, laranja, amarelo, lima, verde, ciano, azul, violeta,
 rosa, roxo, branco, preto, marrom, oliva, bege, cinza]
```

Observe que a ordem das cores é a mesma da lista.

E se alterarmos aquele `.stream()` para `.parallelStream()`, o que acontece? Neste caso, o resultado vai variar por causa do `Thread.sleep` aleatório e por causa do indeterminismo inerente de ver várias threads simultâneas, mas em um teste que fiz o resultado foi esse:

```
[verde, rosa, roxo, ciano, azul, branco, violeta, preto,
vermelho, laranja, amarelo, marrom, oliva, lima, verde, rosa,
roxo, ciano, azul, branco, violeta, preto, vermelho, laranja,
amarelo, marrom, oliva, lima, bege, cinza, verde, rosa,
roxo, ciano, azul, branco, violeta, preto, vermelho, laranja,
amarelo, marrom, oliva, lima, verde, rosa, roxo, ciano,
azul, branco, violeta, preto, vermelho, laranja, amarelo, marrom,
oliva, lima, bege, cinza, verde, rosa, roxo, ciano,
azul, branco, violeta, preto, vermelho, laranja, amarelo, marrom,
oliva, lima, verde, rosa, roxo, ciano, azul, branco,
violeta, preto, vermelho, laranja, amarelo, marrom, oliva, lima,
bege, cinza, verde, rosa, roxo, ciano, azul, branco,
violeta, preto, vermelho, laranja, amarelo, marrom, oliva, lima,
verde, rosa, roxo, ciano, azul, branco, violeta, preto,
vermelho, laranja, amarelo, marrom, oliva, lima, bege, cinza]
```

Bem, esse resultado claramente está muito errado. Isso significa que a implementação do seu `reduce` não funciona em `Stream`s paralelos (mas tenha calma que daqui a pouco explico como consertar isso). Observe que há várias subsequências se repetindo nesse resultado aí.

Olhando a [documentação do método `Stream<T>.reduce(U, BiFunction<U, ? super T, U>, BinaryOperator<U>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(U,java.util.function.BiFunction,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) cujos parâmetros são chamados respectivamente de `identity`, `accumulator` e `combiner`, encontramos isso:

> This is equivalent to:
>
> ```
>  U result = identity;
>  for (T element : this stream)
>      result = accumulator.apply(result, element)
>  return result;
> ```
>
> but is not constrained to execute sequentially.

Traduzindo para o português:

> Isto é equivalente a [código] mas não limitado a executar sequencialmente.

Vamos dar uma olhada primeiro nessa linha:

```
U result = identity;
```

Isso significa que sua `ArrayList` é o primeiro valor de `result`.

Agora essa linha dentro do `for`:

```
    result = accumulator.apply(result, element)
```

Isso significa que a partir da lista dada, uma outra lista será produzida e com base nela uma outra lista e assim sucessivamente até os elementos acabarem. Ocorre que no seu caso a lista produzida é sempre a mesma, e portanto ao invés de você produzir novos resultados com base nos resultados parciais anteriores, você está na verdade modificando os resultados parciais anteriores e os devolvendo como se fossem novos.

O resultado é que ao fazer isso em paralelo, quando o combinador for utilizado, você vai ter que `l1` e `l2` apontam para o mesmo objeto, que é a `ArrayList`, e com isso, **quando você chama `l1.addAll(l2)`, você vai adicionar a lista a ela mesma, o que significa que vai duplicar todos os elementos existentes nela!** Junte isso com o fato das threads em paralelo estarem demorando tempos aleatórios/imprevisíveis e o resultado é aquela bagunça que foi produzida.

Voltando lá no javadoc, também está escrito isso:

> This means that for all `u`, `combiner(identity, u)` is equal to `u`.

Traduzindo:

> Isso significa que para todo `u`, `combiner(identity, u)` é igual a `u`.

Isso significa, de uma forma algébrica, que `identity` deve ser o elemento neutro da operação `combiner`, assim como 0 é o elemento neutro da soma e 1 é o elemento neutro da multiplicação. Qualquer coisa combinada com `identity` deve resultar nessa mesma coisa.

O `combiner` é o seu último lambda que faz o `addAll`. Em seus dois lambdas você altera a lista, e portanto você altera o que é considerado `identity`. Logo, ao invocar `combiner(identity, u)` você acaba tendo uma lista que não é igual ao que o `u` era antes e sim uma que equivale ao `u` dobrado. Isso significa que os seus lambdas violam as regras definidas pela documentação do `reduce` ao violar a regra do elemento neutro do `combiner`. Assim sendo, é óbvio que coisas ruins vão acontecer.

Podemos alterar algumas coisas nos seus lambdas para restaurar o comportamento/contrato exigido pelo `reduce`:

```
public static <T> List<String> mapReduceParalelo2(
    List<Function<T, String>> funcoes, // inicializa com as diversas funções
    T objetoSobProcessamento) // parâmetro arbitrário
{
    List<String> retornoProcessamento = funcoes
            .parallelStream()
            .map(f -> f.apply(objetoSobProcessamento))
            .reduce(Collections.emptyList(), (listaAcumulada, novoValor) -> {
                List<String> novaLista = listaAcumulada.isEmpty() ? new ArrayList<>() : listaAcumulada;
                novaLista.add(novoValor);
                return novaLista;
            }, (l1, l2) -> {
                if (l1.isEmpty()) return l2;
                if (l2.isEmpty()) return l1;
                l1.addAll(l2);
                return l1;
            });
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(retornoProcessamento);
}
```

O nome do método é `mapReduceParalelo2` porque eu vou chamar o que produziu o resultado bagunçado de `mapReduceParalelo1`. No método `parReduceParalelo2`, note que o `identity` é `Collections.emptyList()`. Fiz isso para enfatizar que o `identity` não deve ser alterado (tentar fazer isso resultaria numa exceção).

O `accumulator` testa se a lista dada é um `identity` para evitar problemas, criando uma nova se não for. Se a lista dada não for um `identity`, então ela pode ser seguramente alterada pois a lista original não seria reutilizada em lugar nenhum se uma nova fosse criada.

Já o `combiner`, verifica se uma das listas é um `identity`, retornando a outra neste caso. Se nenhuma delas for o `identity`, então não há problema em fazer-se o `addAll` ao invés de criar uma nova pois nenhuma das listas originais seriam reutilizadas depois.

A moral da história é que o `identity` sempre é reutilizado, enquanto os demais resultados parciais não são. Se o `identity` fosse sempre recriado ao invés de reutilizado, o `mapReduceParalelo1` funcionaria.

Isso pode ter ficado meio complicado porque na verdade o `reduce` foi projetado para trabalhar com dados imutáveis, ao menos com um `identity` imutável. Embora seja possível usar o `reduce` para coisas mutáveis, o resultado é esse troço meio complicado e confuso que saiu. Já o `collect` é diferente. O `collect` foi de fato projetado para trabalhar com coisas mutáveis. Por exemplo:

```
public static <T> List<String> mapCollectParalelo(
    List<Function<T, String>> funcoes, // inicializa com as diversas funções
    T objetoSobProcessamento) // parâmetro arbitrário
{
    List<String> retornoProcessamento = funcoes
            .parallelStream()
            .map(f -> f.apply(objetoSobProcessamento))
            .collect(ArrayList::new, List::add, List::addAll);
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(retornoProcessamento);
}
```

Observe a simplicidade dos parâmetros do [método `collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)). Observe que todos os três parâmetros são *method-references*. O primeiro, ao invés de ser um objeto fixo para servir de `identity` sempre sendo reutilizado, é o `Supplier` que é usado para criar novas listas, no caso o construtor de `ArrayList`. O segundo parâmetro (`accumulator`) é o que adiciona elementos à lista, ou seja o método `add` (e o resultado dele é `void`, pois a operação esperada aqui é uma mutação). O terceiro parâmetro (`combiner`) que combina elementos é o `addAll` (também `void`). Observe que é usado `parallelStream()`. O resultado é o que se espera (e se fosse sequencial, também é):

```
[vermelho, laranja, amarelo, lima, verde, ciano, azul, violeta,
 rosa, roxo, branco, preto, marrom, oliva, bege, cinza]
```

Talvez você perceba que juntar `ArrayList::new`, `List::add` e `List::addAll` seja um caso bastante frequente e corriqueiro. Será que não dá para encapsular esses três num objeto só? Bem, é para isso que serve a [interface `Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html). E o [método `collect(Collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) é a versão de `collect` que utiliza tal interface. Para obter então um `Collector` que cria a lista usando esses três parâmetros, basta usar o [método `Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()). Logo, você pode usar o `collect` simplesmente assim:

```
    List<String> retornoProcessamento = funcoes
            .parallelStream()
            .map(f -> f.apply(objetoSobProcessamento))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Esse último deve ser o código que você queria. Observe que é muito mais simples e direto do que o que você postou em sua pergunta!

[**Coloquei o código completo e compilável no GitHub.**](https://github.com/victorwss/stack-exchange-posts/tree/master/sopt/q316014)

Por fim, quanto à [resposta do OnoSendai que você linkou na pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195246/132), aquilo é sobre JavaScript, e não Java. O modelo do JavaScript é totalmente *single-threaded*, então não há muito o que se falar de paralelismo lá.

Comment: Eu creio que você tenha matado a minha próxima pergunta: quando usar `reduce` e quando usar `collect`