# É possível converter um número inteiro em um Array em C ou PHP?

Tags: php, c, c++

Por exemplo:

```
num = 5634;

array[num];

array[0] = 5;
array[1] = 6;
array[2] = 3;
array[3] = 4;
```

Expliquei de uma forma muito leiga acredito eu, mas queria saber se e possível uma variável receber um numero inteiro e pegar cada digito e colocar em um array.

Comment: Diversas respostas [desta pergunta sobre números](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239450/64969) tratam disso, nas mais diversas linguagens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em PHP você consegue isto facilmente com a função `str_split()`.

Segue exemplo:

```
<?php
    $num = strval(5634);

    $array = str_split($num);

//Retorno: Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 6 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )
?>
```

A função `str_split()` Converte uma string para um array

---

Como explicou o Woss abaixo, quando utilizar a função `str_split` com números, poderá sim gerar erros, para isso, podemos trabalhar com a função `strval()` antes do número, isto fará a conversão para string, evitando possíveis erros posteriormente.

Segue exemplo funcional no [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dcng-9bpj)

Comment: Acha conveniente adicionar à sua resposta a explicação de por que a função funciona quando você passa um **número**, enquanto ela *converte* uma **string** em *array*? Isto é, por que não deu erro ao passar um número?

Comment: @Woss a falta de sentido não está na resposta quando a pergunta mistura linguagens de nível de tipagem e paradigmas diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

Em `PHP` você consegue fazer com a função [str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php).

```php
<?php

$num = 5634;

$array = str_split($num);

print_r($array);
```