# Como passar um inteiro com dois dígitos, fazendo com que cada dígito fique em uma posição no vetor?

Tags: c, array

Faço a soma de dois números 5 e 5, **como fazer para passar o resultado (10) da seguinte forma**:
`vetor[0]=1` e `vetor[1]=0`, ou seja, separar o resultado para cada posição do meu vetor, sem que o `vetor[0]` receba o valor completo que seria `vetor[0]=10`.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Separar inteiro por caractere](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91308/separar-inteiro-por-caractere)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prezado,

Usando divisão sucessiva você consegue separar um decimal. 
Aí é com você para guardar cada algarismo no vetor :-)

```
int numero = 520;
while (numero > 0) {
 int algarismo = numero % 10;
 // faça alguma coisa com o algarismo
 numero /= 10;
}
```